# What's the best way to take a segment out of a text file?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

What's a good way of extracting say, lines 20 -45 out of a huge text file. Non-interactively of course!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you could try:

```
cat textfile | head -n 45 | tail -n 26
```

**or**

```
cat textfile | awk "20 <= NR && NR <= 45"
```

**update:**

As Mahomedalid pointed out, `cat` is not necessary and a bit redundant, but it does make for a clean, readable command.

If `cat` does bother you, a better sollution would be:

```
<textfile awk "20 <= NR && NR <= 45"
```

Comment: `awk NR==20,NR==45 textfile` works too, and reads easily.

Comment: I like the the use of stdin more, it has some global consistancy with the rest of nix

Comment: Reading from command line arguments has consistency with other UNIX utilities too, and my main point was to demonstrate awk's `,` range operator.

Comment: lol, i meant @adam. but yes, I like your suggestion

Comment: I think @ephemient's answer is the best one here. Otherwise, the commands are rather cryptic.

Answer (score 13):

Even simpler:

```
sed -n '20,45p;45q' < textfile
```

The -n flag disables the default output. The "20,45" addresses lines 20 to 45, inclusive. The "p" command prints the current line. And the q quits after printing the line.

Comment: +1 nice, i Like, but its line 20 to 45 :)

Comment: ok ok, I edited it to say 20,45 :-)

Comment: Removing the `q` command (everything starting from `;`) improved performance for me when extracting single line 26995107 from a 27169334-line file.

Answer (score 7):

This is not an answer but can't post it as a comment.

Another (very fast) way to do it was suggested by *mikeserv* [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177570):

```
{ head -n 19 >/dev/null; head -n 26; } <infile
```

Using the same test file as [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194015) and the same procedure, here are some benchmarks (extracting lines 1000020-1000045):

*mikeserv*:

```
{ head -n 1000019 >/dev/null; head -n 26; } <iplist

real    0m0.059s
```

*Stefan*:

```
head iplist -n 1000045 | tail -n 26

real    0m0.054s
```

These are by far the fastest solutions and the differences are negligible *(for a single pass)* (I tried with different ranges: a couple of lines, millions of lines etc).

Doing it without the pipe might offer a significant advantage, however, to an application which needed to seek over *multiple ranges* of lines in similar fashion, like:

```
for  pass in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
do   printf "pass#$pass:\t"
     head -n99 >&3; head -n1
done <<1000LINES 3>/dev/null
$(seq 1000)
1000LINES
```

...which prints...

```
pass#0: 100
pass#1: 200
pass#2: 300
pass#3: 400
pass#4: 500
pass#5: 600
pass#6: 700
pass#7: 800
pass#8: 900
pass#9: 1000
```

...and only reads the file through the one time.

---

The other `sed`/`awk`/`perl` solutions read the whole file and since this is about huge files, they're not very efficient. I threw in some alternatives that `exit` or `q`uit after the last line in the specified range:

*Stefan*:

```
awk "1000020 <= NR && NR <= 1000045" iplist

real    0m2.448s
```

vs.

```
awk "NR >= 1000020;NR==1000045{exit}" iplist

real    0m0.243s
```

*dkagedal* (`sed`):

```
sed -n 1000020,1000045p iplist

real    0m0.947s
```

vs.

```
sed '1,1000019d;1000045q' iplist

real    0m0.143s
```

*Steven D*:

```
perl -ne 'print if 1000020..1000045' iplist

real    0m2.041s
```

vs.

```
perl -ne 'print if $. >= 1000020; exit if $. >= 1000045;' iplist

real    0m0.369s
```

Comment: +1 I think this is the best answer here! It would be nice to get how much it takes time with this `awk NR==1000020,NR==1000045 textfile` in your system.

Answer (score 3):

```
ruby -ne 'print if 20 .. 45' file
```

Comment: a fellow rubyist, you get my vote sir

Comment: While we're at it, why not `python -c 'import fileinput, sys; [sys.stdout.write(line) for nr, line in enumerate(fileinput.input()) if 19 <= nr <= 44]'` too?  :-P  This is something that Ruby, modeled after Perl, inspired by awk/sed, can do easily.

Answer (score 2):

Since sed and awk were already taken, here is a perl solution:

```
perl -nle "print if ($. > 19 && $. < 46)" < textfile
```

Or, as pointed out in the comments:

```
perl -ne 'print if 20..45' textfile
```

Comment: What's with all those extra characters?  No need to strip and re-add newlines, flip-flop assumes comparison to line number, and diamond operator runs through arguments if provided.  `perl -ne'print if 20..45' textfile`

Comment: Nice. -nle is a bit of a reflex I suppose, as for the rest, I have no excuse save ignorance.