# How can I cut a large file in place?

Tags: text-processing, files

I have a very big text file, about 80GB, and I need to cut a part form it that lies between two given lines. The part I need is not big, and I have not enough space left on the hard drive to do things like:

```
head -n 10000000 filename > auxiliary_part
tail -n 1000 auxiliary_part > needed_part
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Also consider one of the answers here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/whats-the-best-way-to-take-a-segment-out-of-a-text-file

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
sed -n '3,10p' big-file.txt > your-section.txt
```

Replace 3 and 10 with your range of lines. The sed commands basically says print (`p`) everything between lines 3 and 10. The `-n` tells it to do it quietly, otherwise it prints out the input as its reading the file.

Comment: Since the OP specifies a large file, if the desired lines are not near the end of the file, then it may also be useful to include a `q` command so that *sed* can skip the rest of the file. Something like `3,$p;10q` would work and keep you from having to repeat the ending line number.

Answer (score 8):

Pipe one to the other:

```
head -n 10000000 filename | tail -n 1000 > needed_part
```