# Print lines between (and excluding) two patterns

Tags: text-processing, sed

I'm going to submit form using cURL, where some of the contents is come from other file, selected using `sed`

If `param1` is line matching pattern from other file using `sed`, below command will works fine:

```
curl -d param1="$(sed -n '/matchpattern/p' file.txt)" -d param2=value2 http://example.com/submit
```

Now, go to the problem. I want show only text between 2 matching pattern excluding the matching pattern itself.

Lets say `file.txt` contains:

```
Bla bla bla
firstmatch
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
secondmatch
The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.
```

Currently, lots of "beetween 2 matching pattern" `sed` command won't remove `firstmatch` and `secondmatch`.

I want the result to become:

```
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988756/how-to-select-lines-between-two-marker-patterns-which-may-occur-multiple-times-w

Answer (score 17):

Here is one way you could do it:

```
sed '1,/firstmatch/d;/secondmatch/,$d'
```

Explained: From the first line to the line matching *firstmatch*, delete. From the line matching *secondmatch* to the last line, delete.

Answer (score 9):

The other `sed` solution will fail if `firstmatch` occurs on the 1st line<sup>1</sup>.

Keep it simple, use a single range and an empty<sup>2</sup> regex:
either print everything in that range excluding range ends (auto-printing disabled)<sup>3</sup>:

```
sed -n '/firstmatch/,/secondmatch/{//!p;}' infile
```

or, shorter, delete everything not in that range and also delete the range ends:

```
sed '/firstmatch/,/secondmatch/!d;//d' infile
```

---

---

<sup>1: The reason being that  [if the second address is a regexp, then checking for the ending match will start with the line following the line which matched the first address](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Range-Addresses).

Therefore, `/firstmatch/` is never evaluated for the 1st line of the input, `sed` will simply delete it as it matches the line number in `1,/RE/` and move on to the 2nd line where it checks if the line matches `/firstpattern/`</sup>

<sup>2: [When a *REGEX* is empty (i.e. `//`) `sed` behaves as if the last *REGEX* used in the last command applied (either as an address or as part of a substitute command) was specified.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_02)</sup>

<sup>3: the `;}`syntax is for modern `sed` implementations; with older ones use either a newline instead of the semicolon or separate expressions e.g. `sed -n -e '/firstmatch/,/secondmatch/{//!p' -e '}' infile`</sup>

Comment: Can you explain what `//` is doing (inside the `{…}`)?

Comment: Thanks, but you fell into my trap. I know that `//` means the last regular expression used; from everything that I’ve read, that should be `/secondmatch/`. I’ve verified through testing that your command works, and so I’ve concluded that it is functioning as `/firstmatch|secondmatch/` (which you have confirmed), but I can’t find any documentation (not even [the POSIX document that you linked to](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_02) or [the GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)) that describes this behavior.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Entertaining experiments: (I) In `sed`: (1) If I do `/first/,4`, then `//` acts like `/first/`.  (2) If I do `2,/second/`, then `//` gets a “no previous regular expression” error.  (I find this a blatant failure to follow the specified behavior.)  (3) Adding `--posix` doesn’t change either of the above.  (II) In other programs: (4) In `vi`, after `/first/,/second/`, `//` acts like `/second/` (and the other forms are also rational implementations of the documented rule).  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (5) `awk` seems to have no notion of “the last RE used”; `//` refers to the non-character before or after any character. (I invite you to try ```echo -- | awk '{ gsub(//, "cha"); print }'```.)

Comment: So, you read “the last REGEX used in the last command” as “the last REGEX(s) used in the last command” and so you (correctly) guessed that it meant `/first|second/`.  Lucky you.  I mention the other programs to demonstrate that this is not some system-wide regex convention.  Whoever added it to `sed` didn’t bother to add it to `vim`, where it would have made just about as much sense.   :-)   ⁠

Comment: Fascinating insight; thanks for sharing.  So now we know that, while the seemingly innocuous specification sentence that you quoted is correct in a cryptic, legalese sort of way, your interpretation of it is not.  On line 2 (location of the `firstmatch`), `//` is equivalent to `/firstmatch/`.  On lines 3 and 4 (location of the `secondmatch`), `//` is equivalent to `/secondmatch/`. Good thing you decided to “keep it simple”; it looks like we both learned something today.    :-)    ⁠

Comment: I can confirm that Busybox sed only removes `/secondmatch/`, and still prints `/firstmatch/`, using either method. Busybox v1.31.1

Answer (score 5):

In awk:

```
awk '
  $1 == "secondmatch" {print_me = 0}
  print_me {print}
  $1 == "firstmatch {print_me = 1}
'
```

Comment: Here about speeds: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194662/16920

Comment: What about the speeds?

Comment: I think SED is here superior in contrast to AWK in time.