# Remove a block of lines between two patterns

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, regular-expression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show only text between 2 matching pattern](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17404/show-only-text-between-2-matching-pattern)

In a bash script using `sed` how can I remove a block of lines beginning with `-pattern a-` and ending with `-pattern b-` where the the contents contains `-pattern c-` ( or does NOT contain `-pattern c-`)?

So :

```
line 1 -pattern a-  
line 2   
line 3 -pattern b-  
line 4 -pattern a-   
line 5 -pattern c-  
line 6 -pattern b-
```

In this example I want to remove lines 4,5 and 6 (or remove 1,2 and 3 for not containing `-pattern c-`).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will always have three consecutive lines, you can use the following:

```
# Print with pattern c
awk 'NR % 3 !=0 {printf $0;printf "|"} NR % 3 ==0 {printf $0; print " "}' file.txt | grep "\-pattern\ c\-" | sed 's/|/\n/g'

# Print without pattern c
awk 'NR % 3 !=0 {printf $0;printf "|"} NR % 3 ==0 {printf $0; print " "}' file.txt | grep -v "\-pattern\ c\-" | sed 's/|/\n/g'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer   The problem is that it is a block with variable quantity of lines and the -pattern c- is not always at the same line