# How do I replace ALL text in a file after a certain line with the content of another text file, using sed/awk?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I am currently trying to automate updating the text of a file, titled original_file.txt. Imagine the file looks like the following:

```
common_text
### REPLACE EVERYTHING AFTER THIS LINE ###
text_that_will
be_removed
after_the_command
```

This file will be updated by removing all text after "Replace everything after this line", and replacing it with the text in the file **replacement_file.txt**. For the sake of the post, imagine that replacement_file.txt has the following text:

```
testing123
this_is_the_replacement_text
```

From what I've been able to find with sed, I can only figure out how to edit the rest of the line after a certain phrase. I want to replace the text in original_file.txt after the replacement phrase with all of the text from replacement_file.txt (I want to keep the replace line text for future updates). original_file.txt should look like this at the end:

```
common_text
### REPLACE EVERYTHING AFTER THIS LINE ###
testing123
this_is_the_replacement_text
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n -e '1,/^### REPLACE EVERYTHING AFTER THIS LINE ###$/{ p; d; }' \
       -e 'r replacement_file.txt' \
       -e 'q' original_file.txt
```

The three `sed` blocks do this:

1. The first block prints all lines from line 1 to the line with the special contents. I print these lines explicitly with `p` and then invoke `d` to force a new cycle to start ("`print; next`" in `awk`).
2. After the initial lines have been outputted by the first block, the second block outputs the contents of the extra file.
3. The editing script is then terminated.

Ordinarily, `q` in the third block would output the current line before quitting (this would be the line in the example data reading `text_that_will`), but since `sed` is invoked with `-n`, this default outputting of a line at the end of a cycle is inhibited.

The result of the above command, given your data, is

```
common_text
### REPLACE EVERYTHING AFTER THIS LINE ###
testing123
this_is_the_replacement_text
```

To update the original file, you could use `sed -i ...`, or redirect the output to a new file that you then replace the original with:

```
sed ... original_file.txt >original_file.txt.new &&
mv original_file.txt.new original_file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me, and I really appreciate the explanation.

Quick clarification question: If instead of '### Replace everything after this line ###', I have a javascript comment which instead reads '//Replace below', how might I do that? I am having trouble writing the sed to account for the special characters '//'. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 15):

In GNU/awk:

Name the two files as arguments.

```
awk '{ print; } /^### REPLACE EVERYTHING AFTER THIS LINE ###$/ { nextfile; }' fn1 fn2
```

Answer (score 14):

Print all lines until "replace after" line is found, then read from other file & quit:

```bsh
sed '/^### REPLACE EVERYTHING AFTER THIS LINE ###$/{r replacement_file.txt
q;}' original_file.txt
```

---

- use `sed -i` to save changes
- or `... > tmp && mv tmp original`

Comment: Neater than mine. Good. Would have been nice with some explanatory text though.

Comment: @Kusalananda this one is also rock solid. Yours would fail to work properly  if `MATCH` was on the 1st line (assuming at least two lines of input) for reasons [explained here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/430154) at `1:`.

Answer (score 6):

This will work efficiently using any awk and cat:

```
$ awk '{print} /### REPLACE EVERYTHING AFTER THIS LINE ###/{exit}' original_file.txt &&
    cat replacement_file.txt
common_text
### REPLACE EVERYTHING AFTER THIS LINE ###
testing123
this_is_the_replacement_text
```

As with any UNIX tools, to update the original just write the output to a temp file and then replace the original with that temp file:

```
{ awk '{print} /### REPLACE EVERYTHING AFTER THIS LINE ###/{exit}' original_file.txt &&
   cat replacement_file.txt; } > tmp && mv tmp original_file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

if using gnu Awk:

```
awk '{print} /### REPLACE.../{system("cat replacement"); exit 0}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to **ed**it a file, prefer `ed` over `sed`:

```
ed -s original_file.txt <<'EOF'
/^### REPLACE/+1,$d
r replacement_file.txt
w
EOF
```

will delete everything after the replace line, insert the contents of the other file, and then save the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Tested and worked fine

Command

```
sed  -ni -e   '1,/#/p' -e '/#/r replacement_file.txt'  titled original_file.txt
```

output

```
common_text
### REPLACE EVERYTHING AFTER THIS LINE ###
testing123
this_is_the_replacement_text
```

Comment: It works with OP input sample but doesn't always work: see my comment under _rowboat_'s answer...

Comment: ok will check thanks