# Reference first and last line of range in grouped commands in sed

Tags: sed

When you use grouped commands in a sed script, is there a way to reference the first and last line of the range you're in?

I want to be able to print the first and last line of a range as well as selected lines between those.

```
#n
/StartLinePattern/,/EndLinePattern/{
  /PatternOfSubLineToPrint/p;
}
```

I know that I can solve this by including another grouped command that *matches* the first and last lines of the range (again); but it would be cleaner, faster, and more reusable to do something akin to the standard for non-grouped commands.

```
1p;$p
```

I tried including the above in the group, but it doesn't work. It appears that `1` and `$` are absolute, not relative to the range you're in.

**Background**

I made a sed script that filters elements out of an XML file. To do this, I use ranges with grouped commands to print certain sub elements within that range. So the script works by printing everything that you want to keep.

```
#n
/<Parent\>/,<\/Parent>/{
  /<Child1\>/,/<\/Child1>/p;
  /<Child2\>/,/<\/Child2>/p;
  /<SingleLineChild\>/p;
}
```

Comment: Better add sample XML input, expected output. `sed` is not a XML parser

Comment: @GillesQuenot The question has nothing to do with XML. The question on the last line of the original post is universal.

Comment: This is [a very bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1081936) and it is impossible to do correctly (OK, it's possible but [very, very hard even for experts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/1081936)). If you have XML, use an XML parser nor ad hoc regular expression parsing.

Comment: For my input files, I can assume that start and end tags are on their own line or both on the same line. So the problem is as simple as "which lines do I want to keep"?
Again, the question has nothing to do with XML.

Comment: So remove XML and use simple lines of plain text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that by using an *empty regex* i.e. `//` as the first regex after the opening `{`
e.g with an input like:

```
hello
world
start
inner1
inner2
inner3
end
outer
```

if you run

```
sed -n '/start/,/end/{
//p
/inner1/p;/inner3/p
}' infile
```

it prints

```
start
inner1
inner3
end
```

You can see [how that works here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/430154)... Just to repost the important part:

*[When a `REGEX` is empty (i.e. `//`) `sed` behaves as if the last `REGEX` used in the last command applied (either as an address or as part of a substitute command) was specified.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_02)*

---

If you wanted to exclude either the start of the range or the end you'd just add another test:

```
sed -n '/start/,/end/{
//{
/start/!p
}
/inner1/p;/inner3/p
}' infile
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I needed, so I'm marking as the accepted answer. It's too bad it doesn't cover the case where you want only the first or last line of the range.

Comment: @Sildoreth - that's easy to manage, see edit.