# cat line X to line Y on a huge file

Tags: tail, cat, large-files, head

Say I have a huge text file (>2GB) and I just want to `cat` the lines `X` to `Y` (e.g. 57890000 to 57890010).

From what I understand I can do this by piping `head` into `tail` or viceversa, i.e.

```
head -A /path/to/file | tail -B
```

or alternatively

```
tail -C /path/to/file | head -D
```

where `A`,`B`,`C` and `D` can be computed from the number of lines in the file, `X` and `Y`.

But there are two problems with this approach:

1. You have to compute `A`,`B`,`C` and `D`.
2. The commands could `pipe` to each other **many more** lines than I am interested in reading (e.g. if I am reading just a few lines in the middle of a huge file)

Is there a way to have the shell just work with and output the lines I want? (while providing only `X` and `Y`)?

Comment: FYI, actual speed test comparison of 6 methods added to my answer.

Comment: See also [What's the best way to take a segment out of a text file?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2072)

Comment: You can consider using the split command too !

Answer (score 174, accepted):

I suggest the `sed` solution, but for the sake of completeness,

```
awk 'NR >= 57890000 && NR <= 57890010' /path/to/file
```

To cut out after the last line:

```
awk 'NR < 57890000 { next } { print } NR == 57890010 { exit }' /path/to/file
```

---

Speed test (here on macOS, YMMV on other systems):

- 100,000,000-line file generated by `seq 100000000 > test.in`
- Reading lines 50,000,000-50,000,010
- Tests in no particular order
- `real` time as reported by `bash`'s builtin `time`

```
 4.373  4.418  4.395    tail -n+50000000 test.in | head -n10
 5.210  5.179  6.181    sed -n '50000000,50000010p;57890010q' test.in
 5.525  5.475  5.488    head -n50000010 test.in | tail -n10
 8.497  8.352  8.438    sed -n '50000000,50000010p' test.in
22.826 23.154 23.195    tail -n50000001 test.in | head -n10
25.694 25.908 27.638    ed -s test.in <<<"50000000,50000010p"
31.348 28.140 30.574    awk 'NR<57890000{next}1;NR==57890010{exit}' test.in
51.359 50.919 51.127    awk 'NR >= 57890000 && NR <= 57890010' test.in
```

These are by no means precise benchmarks, but the difference is clear and repeatable enough* to give a good sense of the relative speed of each of these commands.

*: Except between the first two, `sed -n p;q` and `head|tail`, which seem to be essentially the same.

Comment: Out of curiosity: how have you flushed the disk cache between tests?

Comment: What about `tail -n +50000000 test.in | head -n10`, which unlike `tail -n-50000000 test.in | head -n10` would give the correct result?

Comment: Ok, I went and did some benchmarks. tail|head is way faster than sed, the difference is a lot more than I expected.

Comment: @Gilles you're right, my bad. `tail+|head` is faster by 10-15% than sed, I've added that benchmark.

Comment: @gorkypl I didn't, I figure it should be cached for all of them, certainly by the third iteration.

Comment: I wonder why I'm seeing `sed` being so much slower than `tail|head` and you're seeing only a small difference (which is what I'd expected before doing the benchmark). I did my tests on Debian stable.

Comment: @Gilles I'm on a mac, so BSD utils, but I'd be surprised if the difference between BSD and GNU `head` and `tail` are really so big.

Comment: Humm, `tail -N` has to stash `N` lines somewhere to be able to get the last ones out at the end. Not nice on your memory. I'd vote for `sed` (or `awk` in a pinch, but the whole "split into fields" stuff adds overhead). Just guessing.

Comment: Edited the test: Ran on `/dev/shm` to not use the disk cache but run the whole stuff in memory.

Comment: I realize that the question asks for lines, but if you use the `-c` to skip characters, `tail+|head` is instantaneous. Of course, you can't say "50000000" and may have to manually search out the start of the section you're looking for.

Comment: Don't forget to add `{print; exit}` if you want awk to return, ie: `awk "NR==10{print; exit}" file`

Comment: Hey Guys!!. There are 11 elements from `5...00` to `5...10`. So, all `head -n10` should be corrected to `head -n11`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You ran some of your commands relative to line `50000000` but others to line `57890000`. Unfortunately, this inconsistency isn't confined to independent commands: your 2nd command mixes the 2 unrelated bases: `sed -n '50000000,50000010p;57890010q' test.in` If that's what you actually ran, it would produce an artificially crippled benchmark - by wasting time reading and discarding 7890000 lines that it doesn't need. Or did you run the right command but just transcribe it wrongly here?

Comment: @underscore_d it was 4 years ago, who knows what I ran.  If you want to check, you can run the benchmarks yourself.

Comment: You haven't specified how to pass the filename as parameter

Comment: tail -n+49000000 test.in | head -n10 takes 2 seconds! Beats anything else on dual core + SSD (Linux blade 4.10.0-42-generic #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu)
head -n500200100 zzz | tail -n10 (7 seconds); head -n999200100 zzz | tail -n10 (12 seconds)

Answer (score 78):

If you want lines X to Y inclusive (starting the numbering at 1), use

```
tail -n "+$X" /path/to/file | head -n "$((Y-X+1))"
```

`tail` will read and discard the first X-1 lines (there's no way around that), then read and print the following lines. `head` will read and print the requested number of lines, then exit. When `head` exits, `tail` receives a [SIGPIPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGPIPE) signal and dies, so it won't have read more than a buffer size's worth (typically a few kilobytes) of lines from the input file.

Alternatively, as [gorkypl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47407/cat-line-x-to-line-y-on-a-huge-file/47410#47410) suggested, use sed:

```
sed -n -e "$X,$Y p" -e "$Y q" /path/to/file
```

The sed solution is significantly slower though (at least for GNU utilities and Busybox utilities; sed might be more competitive if you extract a large part of the file on an OS where piping is slow and sed is fast). Here are quick benchmarks under Linux; the data was generated by `seq 100000000 >/tmp/a`, the environment is Linux/amd64, `/tmp` is tmpfs and the machine is otherwise idle and not swapping.

```
real  user  sys    command
 0.47  0.32  0.12  </tmp/a tail -n +50000001 | head -n 10 #GNU
 0.86  0.64  0.21  </tmp/a tail -n +50000001 | head -n 10 #BusyBox
 3.57  3.41  0.14  sed -n -e '50000000,50000010 p' -e '50000010q' /tmp/a #GNU
11.91 11.68  0.14  sed -n -e '50000000,50000010 p' -e '50000010q' /tmp/a #BusyBox
 1.04  0.60  0.46  </tmp/a tail -n +50000001 | head -n 40000001 >/dev/null #GNU
 7.12  6.58  0.55  </tmp/a tail -n +50000001 | head -n 40000001 >/dev/null #BusyBox
 9.95  9.54  0.28  sed -n -e '50000000,90000000 p' -e '90000000q' /tmp/a >/dev/null #GNU
23.76 23.13  0.31  sed -n -e '50000000,90000000 p' -e '90000000q' /tmp/a >/dev/null #BusyBox
```

If you know the byte range you want to work with, you can extract it faster by skipping directly to the start position. But for lines, you have to read from the beginning and count newlines. To extract blocks from x inclusive to y exclusive starting at 0, with a block size of b:

```
dd bs="$b" seek="$x" count="$((y-x))" </path/to/file
```

Comment: Are you sure that there is no caching inbetween? The differences between tail|head and sed seem too big to me.

Comment: @gorkypl I did several measures and the times were comparable. As I wrote, this is all happening in RAM (everything is in the cache).

Comment: @Gilles `tail will read and discard the first X-1 line` seems to be avoided when the number of lines is given from the end, In such case, tail seems to read backwards from the end according to the executing times. Please read: `http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216614/79743`.

Comment: @BinaryZebra Yes, if the input is a regular file, some implementations of `tail` (including GNU tail) have heuristics to read from the end. That improves the `tail | head` solution compared to other methods.

Answer (score 31):

The `head | tail` approach is one of the best and most "idiomatic" ways to do this:

```
X=57890000
Y=57890010
< infile.txt head -n "$Y" | tail -n +"$X"
```

As pointed out by Gilles in the comments, a faster way is

```
< infile.txt tail -n +"$X" | head -n "$((Y - X))"
```

The reason this is faster is the first *X - 1* lines don't need to go through the pipe compared to the `head | tail` approach.

Your question as phrased is a bit misleading and probably explains some of your unfounded misgivings towards this approach.

- You say you have to calculate `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` but as you can see, the line count of the file is not needed and at most 1 calculation is necessary, which the shell can do for you anyways.
- You worry that piping will read more lines than necessary.  In fact this is not true: `tail | head` is about as efficient as you can get in terms of file I/O.  First, consider the minimum amount of work necessary: to find the *X*'th line in a file, the only general way to do it is to read every byte and stop when you count *X* newline symbols as there is no way to divine the file offset of the *X*'th line.  Once you reach the *X*th line, you have to read all the lines in order to print them, stopping at the *Y*'th line.  Thus no approach can get away with reading less than *Y* lines.  Now, `head -n $Y` reads no more than *Y* lines (rounded to the nearest buffer unit, but buffers if used correctly improve performance, so no need to worry about that overhead).  In addition, `tail` will not read any more than `head`, so thus we have shown that `head | tail` reads the fewest number of lines possible (again, plus some negligible buffering that we are ignoring).  The only efficiency advantage of a single tool approach that does not use pipes is fewer processes (and thus less overhead).

Comment: Never seen the redirection go first on the line before. Cool, it makes the pipe flow clearer.

Answer (score 20):

The most orthodox way (but not the fastest, as noted by [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47424/16705) above) would be to use `sed`.

In your case:

```
X=57890000
Y=57890010
sed -n -e "$X,$Y p" -e "$Y q" filename
```

The `-n` option implies that only the relevant lines are printed to stdout.

The **p** at the end of finishing line number means to print lines in given range.
The **q** in second part of the script saves some time by skipping the remainder of the file.

Comment: I expected `sed` and `tail | head` to be about on par, but it turns out that `tail | head` is significantly faster (see [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47407/cat-line-x-to-line-y-on-a-huge-file/47424#47424)).

Comment: I dunno, from what I've read, `tail`/`head` are considered more "orthodox", since trimming either end of a file is precisely what they're made for. In those materials, `sed` only seems to enter the picture when substitutions are required - and to quickly be pushed out of the picture when anything much more complex starts to happen, since its syntax for complex tasks is so much worse than AWK, which then takes over.

Answer (score 7):

If we know the range to select, from the first line: `lStart` to the last line: `lEnd` we could calculate:

```
lCount="$((lEnd-lStart+1))"
```

If we know the total amount of lines: `lAll` we also could calculate the distance to the end of the file:

```
toEnd="$((lAll-lStart+1))"
```

Then we will know both:

```
"how far from the start"            ($lStart) and
"how far from the end of the file"  ($toEnd).
```

Choosing the smallest of any of those: `tailnumber` as this:

```
tailnumber="$toEnd"; (( toEnd > lStart )) && tailnumber="+$linestart"
```

Allows us to use the consistently fastest executing command:

```
tail -n"${tailnumber}" ${thefile} | head -n${lCount}
```

Please note the additional plus ("+") sign when `$linestart` is selected.

The only caveat is that we need the total count of lines, and that may take some additional time to find.
As is usual with:

```
linesall="$(wc -l < "$thefile" )"
```

---

## Some times measured are:

```
lStart |500| lEnd |500| lCount |11|
real   user   sys    frac
0.002  0.000  0.000  0.00  | command == tail -n"+500" test.in | head -n1
0.002  0.000  0.000  0.00  | command == tail -n+500 test.in | head -n1
3.230  2.520  0.700  99.68 | command == tail -n99999501 test.in | head -n1
0.001  0.000  0.000  0.00  | command == head -n500 test.in | tail -n1
0.001  0.000  0.000  0.00  | command == sed -n -e "500,500p;500q" test.in
0.002  0.000  0.000  0.00  | command == awk 'NR<'500'{next}1;NR=='500'{exit}' test.in


lStart |50000000| lEnd |50000010| lCount |11|
real   user   sys    frac
0.977  0.644  0.328  99.50 | command == tail -n"+50000000" test.in | head -n11
1.069  0.756  0.308  99.58 | command == tail -n+50000000 test.in | head -n11
1.823  1.512  0.308  99.85 | command == tail -n50000001 test.in | head -n11
1.950  2.396  1.284  188.77| command == head -n50000010 test.in | tail -n11
5.477  5.116  0.348  99.76 | command == sed -n -e "50000000,50000010p;50000010q" test.in
10.124  9.669  0.448  99.92| command == awk 'NR<'50000000'{next}1;NR=='50000010'{exit}' test.in


lStart |99999000| lEnd |99999010| lCount |11|
real   user   sys    frac
0.001  0.000  0.000  0.00  | command == tail -n"1001" test.in | head -n11
1.960  1.292  0.660  99.61 | command == tail -n+99999000 test.in | head -n11
0.001  0.000  0.000  0.00  | command == tail -n1001 test.in | head -n11
4.043  4.704  2.704  183.25| command == head -n99999010 test.in | tail -n11
10.346  9.641  0.692  99.88| command == sed -n -e "99999000,99999010p;99999010q" test.in
21.653  20.873  0.744  99.83 | command == awk 'NR<'99999000'{next}1;NR=='99999010'{exit}' test.in
```

Note that times change drastically if the selected lines are near the start or near the end. A command which appear to work nicely at one side of the file, may be extremely slow at the other side of the file.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25986/discussion-on-answer-by-binaryzebra-cat-line-x-to-line-y-on-a-huge-file).

Comment: @BinaryZebra - *way* better.

Answer (score 0):

I do this often enough and so wrote this script. I don't need to find the line numbers, the script does it all.

```
#!/bin/bash

# $1: start time
# $2: end time
# $3: log file to read
# $4: output file

# i.e. log_slice.sh 18:33 19:40 /var/log/my.log /var/log/myslice.log

if [[ $# != 4 ]] ; then 
echo 'usage: log_slice.sh <start time> <end time> <log file> <output file>'
echo
exit;
fi

if [ ! -f $3 ] ; then
echo "'$3' doesn't seem to exit."
echo 'exiting.'
exit;
fi

sline=$(grep -n " ${1}" $3|head -1|cut -d: -f1)  #what line number is first occurrance of start time
eline=$(grep -n " ${2}" $3|head -1|cut -d: -f1)  #what line number is first occurrance of end time

linediff="$((eline-sline))"

tail -n+${sline} $3|head -n$linediff > $4
```

Comment: You're answering a question that wasn't asked. Your answer is 10% `tail|head`, which has been discussed extensively in the question and the other answers, and 90% determining the line numbers where specified strings/patterns appear, which ***wasn't part of the question***. P.S. you should always quote your shell parameters and variables; e.g., "$3" and "$4".

Answer (score -1):

If you **cat** the data you will want to use tail first and then head.

```
cat file.name | tail -n +"3" | head -n -"1"
```

Comment: Pretty much every other answer has at least mentioned, if not recommended, `tail` piped into `head`.  Adding a `cat` to the pipeline just adds noise and overhead, but doesn’t add value.  You might as well say “If you’re wearing gloves when you type the command, you will want to use tail first and then head.” — it doesn’t matter.

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me.

Comment: You say “This is ***the*** solution that worked for me.” [emphasis added] I say it is ***a*** solution that works.  Did you try `tail -n +3 file.name | head -n -1`?  What happened?

Answer (score -1):

even the fastest `tail + head` combo is only like **`1.3 %`** faster than `awk` :

> ```
> __='147654389'   # extracting rows 147,654,389 - 147,654,399
> ```

---

```
  ( time ( pvE0 < "$_____" | 

    mawk2 -v __=$__ 'BEGIN {_=(__=+__)+10}NR<__{next}_<NR{exit}_' ))  

  in0: 7.17GiB 0:00:05 [1.33GiB/s] [1.33GiB/s] [=====> ] 94%            
   ( pvE 0.1 in0 < "$_____" | mawk2 -v __=$__ ; )  

   4.65s user 1.79s system 118% cpu 5.424 total

   02de381a4ea9c6d101c1935ae75cf565  stdin
```

---

```
  in0: 7.17GiB 0:00:05 [1.34GiB/s] [1.34GiB/s] [=====> ] 94%            
  ( pvE 0.1 in0 < "$_____" | 

                 gtail -n"+$__" | ghead -n11; )  

  2.50s user 3.96s system 120% cpu 5.355 total

  02de381a4ea9c6d101c1935ae75cf565  stdin
```

---

*ironically, `gnu-tail` is actually ***slower*** when using its own `I/O` mechanism to read the file instead of through the pipe*