# Easy way to copy lines from one file to another

Tags: text-processing, files, large-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [cat line X to line Y on a huge file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47407/cat-line-x-to-line-y-on-a-huge-file)

Very simple issue but can't seem to find a simple resolution!

I have a massive text file from which I only need around 150 lines. The lines are really long and therefore viewing it in putty is a bit of a nightmare. I just want to copy these lines to another file so that I can view it properly in an editor. (I can't view the original file in an editor as my Windows machine can't handle it).

The lines I want start at around line 2000.

Thanks,

Comment: If you have xsel installed you could use sed with xsel. `sed -n '2000,2150p' youfile| xsel`

Comment: @McNisse Why do you need `xsel`?

Comment: To copy the lines directly into the clipboard.

Comment: If bandwidth is not an issue, you can use editor or pager like `more` or `less` remotely. Remember to resize the PuTTY window to get some more context.

Comment: @McNisse "I just want to copy these lines to another file"

Comment: @Berndard: "... so I view it properly in an editor." I got the idea that Rich wanted the lines in an editor in windows. With `xsel` there  is no need to copy the file as well.

Answer (score 11):

I have an easy shell function for it (put in `.bashrc`), which uses `sed`

```
printLine () 
{ 
    sed -n -e "$1p" "$2"
}
```

You can easily use it by

```
$ printLine 2000,2250 file
```

I am using the function, because I always forget the correct `sed`-syntax.

You want to store the output in a different file, than it is easy:

```
$ printLine 2000,2250 file > output
```

Comment: I'm using ksh (should have mentioned that) and printLine doesn't work :S

Comment: Sorted it... thanks to kev82 here - http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/cat-output-specific-number-of-lines-130360/

The following outputs lines 10 to 30...

Comment: `head -30 text.file | tail -20 > output.file`

Comment: @Rich ksh also supports functions, afaik, so  you can probably easily port it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just look for a certain token, the `grep` command could be useful.

```
cat filename | grep pattern > extractedFilename
```

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question. Also, why are you using `cat` here?