# How to get lines 10 to 100 from a 200 line file into a new file

Tags: text-processing, sed, tail, head

I have file with 200 lines.

I need to extract lines from 10 to 100 and put them into a new file.

How do you do this in unix/Linux?

What are the possible commands you could use?

Comment: Actually, this would be incredibly easy to do with `vim`, but I imagine, if you really wanted to do this without an editor, your best bet is likely `awk`.

Comment: @HalosGhost care to post your answer?

Comment: @Creek, [posted](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138403/65525) per request.

Answer (score 58):

Use [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/):

```
sed -n -e '10,100p' input.txt > output.txt
```

`sed -n` means **don't** print each line by default. `-e` means execute the next argument as a sed script. `10,100p` is a sed script that means starting on line 10, until line 100 (inclusive), print (`p`) that line. Then the output is saved into `output.txt`.

If your file is longer than suggested, this version (suggested in the comments) will be faster:

```
sed -e '1,9d;100q'
```

That means **delete** lines 1-9, **quit** after line 100, and print the rest. For 200 lines it's not going to matter, but for 200,000 lines the first version will still look at every line even when it's never going to print them. I prefer the first version in general for being explicit, but with a long file this will be much faster — you know your data best.

Alternatively, you can use `head` and `tail` in combination:

```
tail -n +10 input.txt | head -n 91 > output.txt
```

This time, `tail -n +10` prints out the entire file starting from line 10, and `head -n 91` prints the first 91 lines of that (up to and including line 100 of the original file). It's redirected to `output.txt` in the same way.

Comment: That's probably better like `sed '1,9d;100q'`. Faster anyway.

Comment: Fair comment. For 200 lines it doesn't matter and I prefer the more explicit version, but if it's much longer quitting (or head/tail) is definitely better. I've edited in the option anyway.

Comment: `head | tail` will still win every time - especially because they only each do half the job but do it concurrently.

Comment: @mikeserv but that's using 2 commands, `sed` alone should be faster

Comment: Not for 91 lines they won't. I actually tested this - spawning two processes was about 8% slower than a single sed.

Comment: @MichaelHomer I clocked `real    0m0.006s` vs. `real    0m0.015s`

Comment: @Creek and Homer - in a situation where it matters - as in the file is large enough to take longer to read than spawning the processes to read it, `head | tail` will win every time. But not for 91 linews they won't, as you say, Homer. http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/47407/52934

Comment: how can I specify the end of file. Such as from line 10 to the end of file?

Answer (score 9):

This should do

`tail -n +10 file.txt | head -n 91 > newfile.txt`

Answer (score 7):

If you were to do this in `vim`, it'd be pretty simple. Assume your file is named `src` and the file you wish to move the lines to is `dest`. If `dest` doesn't already exist, you would create it:

```
touch dest
```

Then, open both `src` and `dest` in `vim` (the `-p` flag opens the arguments in tabs):

```
vim -p src dest
```

Jump to the tenth line; select everything from the 10th line to the 100th line; yank; switch to the tab containing `dest`; paste.

```
10ggv101ygtp
```

*Note*: the `101` selects to the beginning of the 101st line (catches the `\n` at the end of line 100).

---

That is obviously a little more involved process than using a command-line tool, but does have the advantage of giving you a visual selection (so you can be sure you get everything you want). However, this also seems like a fine use-case for `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==10, NR==100' src > dest
```

The `NR` variable allows you to pattern-match against the number of lines. Thus, the above command, extracts lines 10–100 from `src` and then your shell redirects the output to `dest`.

Comment: `vim` is overkill but IMHO `awk` wins

Comment: @Creek, in retrospect, using a full editor for this process is probably overkill, yes. However, I think (read: dream) in `vim` anymore; I can't help it :P

Comment: there is no escape

Answer (score 3):

You can do it many ways.

An `awk` solution:

```
$ awk 'NR<10{next};1;NR>100{exit}' file > new_file
```

A `perl` solution:

```
$ perl -nle '
    print if $. > 9 and $. < 101;
    exit if $. > 100;
' file > new_file
```