# Only cat from specific line X (with a pattern) to other specific line Y (with a pattern)

Tags: sed, awk, grep, tail, head

A little extended problem from "[cat line x to line y on a huge file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47407/cat-line-x-to-line-y-on-a-huge-file)":

I have a huge file (2-3 GB). I'd like to cat/print only from the line having "foo:" to the line having "goo:". Assume that "foo:" and "goo:" only appear once in a file; "foo:" proceeds "goo:".

So far this is my approach:

- First, find the line with "foo:" and "goo:": `grep -nr "foo:" bigfile`
- Returns `123456: foo: hello world!` and `654321: goo: good bye!`
- Once I know these starting and ending line numbers, and the difference (654321-123456=530865) I can do selective cat:
- `tail -n+123456 bigfile | head -n 530865`

My question is that how can I effectively substitute the line number constants with expressions (e.g., grep ...)?

I can write a simple Python script but want to achieve it using only combining commands.

Answer (score 9):

```
sed -n '/foo/,/goo/p;/goo/q' <bigfile
```

That would print only those lines. If you wanted the line numbers you'd add an `=`.

```
sed -n '/foo/=;/goo/=;//q' <bigfile
```

The `q` is important because it `q`uits the input when it is called - else `sed` will continue to read the infile through to the end.

If you don't want to print `foo/goo` lines you can do instead:

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -n '/foo/,/goo/!d;//!p;/goo/q
' <<\DATA
line1
foo 
line3
line4
line5
goo 
line7
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT

```
line3
line4
line5
```

And with any other:

```
sed -n '/foo/G;/\n/,/goo/!d;//q;/\n/!p 
' <<\DATA
line1
foo 
line3
line4
line5
goo 
line7
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT

```
line3
line4
line5
```

Either way, though, this also quits its input as soon as it encounters the last line in your search.

Comment: what's the advantage of that longer `sed` command over `sed -n '/foo:/!{ /goo:/,/foo:/!p; }' bigFile`? (Not being argumentative; generally curious.)

Comment: @HalosGhost - I edited it. Thanks for the inspiration - your own answer gets my vote.

Comment: Thank you! I removed the `sed` solution in my post considering that what I posted was not actually equivalent (in execution flow) to my `awk` solution. I'll leave my post to `awk` :)

Comment: `sed -n '/foo/,/goo/!d;//!p;/goo/q'` won't work with all `sed` implementations (`//!p` will only match on `goo` with some).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - which are those if you don't mind? That confuses me - specifically the [note here about `c`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html)`[2addr]c\
text`
*Delete the pattern space. With a 0 or 1 address or at the **end of a 2-address range**, place text on the output and start the next cycle.* Maybe I should make that a question, huh? It's just that - GNU `sed` at, least - seems to do all of them. Or else, when used like I do above, only the specifically addressed lines. Is it a bug, do you think?

Comment: In the original one (tested on Unix V7) and probably all the derived commercial Unices (tested Solaris as well) as well as FreeBSD (and probably all the BSDs). `ls / | sed -n '/dev/,/lib/!d;//!p;/lib/q'` shows `dev`. Only exception I've found so far is GNU sed.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - I think it's a GNU bug, maybe. I've been up and down their `sed` `info` pages and I've never noticed any reference to that behavior. Not doing so does seem a little out-of-character considering the explicit coverage of `N` and its last line behavior in the BUGS section. I suppose I should report it. Anyway, I updated the answer to reflect it.

Comment: Both make sense. `//` matches on the last pattern. For GNU `sed`, it'll be the last pattern match _run_, while on other `sed`s, that'll be the last one lexically on the sed command script (even though it was not run. `/goo/` is not run in `/foo/,/goo/` if `/foo/` matched). I would even say that the GNU sed behaviour is more inline with the POSIX spec.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - so your point is that it is a bug in the spec for it not being specific enough? But what of the `/ran/,/ge/c\\ ` behavior? They seem related... And besides, in my example - if it really were doing the range again - then shouldn't it `!p` the whole range? I didn't even see your answer till just now...

Comment: I'd say yes, the spec is not specific enough. I don't see what's the problem with `c` though. That seems unambiguous to me and I don't see how that's related to `//`. The ambiguity is about what `//` matches on when the previous match is part of a `/x/,/y/` address range. There's also ambiguity in `ls / | sed '/s/s/i/u/;s//<&>/g'` for instance.

Answer (score 5):

If you are okay with abandoning your current approach of using something in subshells to get the line numbers and allowing another utility to print the file, this can be accomplished in pure `awk` with little difficulty:

If you wish to print the lines *between* `foo:` and `goo:` and not the lines themselves, then you can use the following ([picked up from here originally](http://nixtip.wordpress.com/2010/10/12/print-lines-between-two-patterns-the-awk-way/)):

```
awk '/goo:/ { exit }; flag; /foo:/ { flag = 1 }' bigFile
```

The above `exit`s when it sees the end token (`goo:`), `print`s if `flag` is true, and sets `flag` to true (`1`, actually) when it reaches the opening token (`foo:`).

If, however, you would prefer to include the token lines in the output, the command is actually even simpler, as [@jasonwryan mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153239/only-cat-from-specific-line-x-with-a-pattern-to-other-specific-line-y-with-a#comment250190_153244):

```
awk '/foo:/,/goo:/' bigFile
```

---

If you are hell-bent on only getting the line numbers and not actually printing the file with the same utility, then you can get the line numbers of the start and end tokens like so:

```
awk '/foo:|goo:/ { print NR }' bigFile
```

Comment: Or, if you want the matches as well: `awk '/foo/,/goo/' bigfile`

Answer (score 4):

Alternative `sed` one:

```
sed '/foo/,$!d;/goo/q'
```

Answer (score 1):

To substitute the constants with expressions, you can use [command substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution).

To substitute the output of a command into an expression, use `$(command)`

In this case, the appropriate command line is:

```
tail -n+$(grep -nr "foo:" bigfile | cut -d':' -f1) bigfile | \
head -n$(($(grep -nr "goo:" bigfile | cut -d':' -f1)-$(grep -nr "foo:" bigfile | cut -d':' -f1)+1))
```

This will print all lines from the line containing `foo:` to the line containing `goo:`, inclusive.

Comment: This reads the input file at least 4 times. You would do better to `grep` both in one `$((` arithmetic `))` evaluation statement and save the results into variables.