# head, tail, and then line?

Tags: text-processing

What is the simplest way to extract from a file a line given by its number. E.g., I want the 666th line of `somefile`. How would you do this in your terminal, or in a shell script?

I can see solutions like `head -n 666 somefile | tail -n 1`, or even the half-incorrect `cat -n somefile | grep -F 666`, but there must be something nicer, faster, and more robust. Maybe using a more obscure unix command/utility?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12182910/1331399

Comment: It really doesn't get much faster or robust than the head/tail approach. My Perl solution is as fast or slightly faster in some cases (but the inverse will probably be true in others). The only "nicer" one will be the `awk 'NR==666` but that, while shorter, is significantly slower.

Comment: @phs Please post your 'PS' as comments to the individual answerers. It has nothing to do with the question content and should not be part of one. Apart from that it triggered a spurious reopen review cycle.

Answer (score 23):

**sed** (**s**tream **ed**itor) is the right tool for this kind of job:

`sed -n '666p' somefile`

Edit: @tachomi's solution `sed '666q;d' somefile` is better when operating on a huge text file, because it makes **sed** exit after printing the pattern without reading the rest of the file. On all other files, the difference is irrelevant.

Comment: @dr01: Thanks! I only use `sed` for replacements, e.g. `sed -e "s/../../g"`, sometimes with regular expressions, and always felt that `sed`'s manual and its full list of commands was too painful for me. So here `-n` is don't echo, `666` is an address, and `p` is `print`?

Comment: Yes. `sed` is a powerful tool, it is worth learning all its options.

Comment: `sed -n '666{p;q}' somefile` unless your `sed` dialect won't accept that and requires `sed -n -e '10{p' -e 'q}' somefile` This allows you to quit early without the conceptual dissonance of "deleting" the lines that you don't want printed. It's merely a stylistic alternative.

Answer (score 18):

You can use sed

```
sed -n '666p' somefile
```

Or

```
sed '666!d' somefile
```

Or in large files

```
sed '666q;d' somefile
```

In bash script

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
line=666
sed "$line"'q;d' somefile
```

Comment: Why distinguish between large file and non-large file when they're a couple chars different?

Comment: `/usr/bin/bash` is a decidedly non-standard location. You on Arch Linux or something? O.o

Comment: The redirection on the very last line is unnecessary.

Answer (score 7):

POSIXly (and maybe the fastest with huge file):

```
tail -n +666 | head -n1
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: This solution has already been suggested by the OP and correctly discarded as it uses two processes.

Comment: @dr01: No, the OP use `head` then `tail`, which is very different from `tail` then `head`.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but isn't the `sed` command POSIX compliant too?

Comment: It doesn't matter; there's no need to use two commands when you can use one.

Comment: @dr01: Run your `sed` and mine with the file a huge file, and you can see the different. Yours is even worse than tachomy, since you read the rest of the file instead of quitting after hit the line. Read [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47407/cat-line-x-to-line-y-on-a-huge-file) for more details.

Comment: @EricRenouf: The `sed` is compliant.

Comment: @cuonglm Good point. +1 for speed.

Comment: I tested this on a ~6M and a ~848M file and my Perl approach was faster on both. Also, the OP's approach was exactly as fast as yours, why do you say that tail/head will be better than head/tail?

Comment: @terdon: You can see the same issue and benchmark [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47423/38906).

Comment: Hmm. I don't see the same result here. My guess is that it will depend on the size of the file and how close to the end the desired line is. Sometimes head/tail will be faster and other times tail/head will.

Answer (score 6):

try

```
awk 'NR == 666 { print ; exit ; } '
```

or

```
awk -vline=$LINE 'NR == line { print ;  exit ; } ' 
awk 'NR == '$LINE' { print ; exit ;  } '
```

if you want to provide line number via a shell variable ($LINE) .

e[dx]it: as per terdon suggestion.

Comment: You don't need that. Remember that awk treats any statement evaluating to true as a call to `print`. That's why `1;` will print the line. All you need is `awk 'NR==666`.

Comment: That wasn't my suggestion, it was yours! My suggestion was `awk 'NR==666` which is as slow as your original but shorter. The `exit;` makes all the difference!

Comment: the exit in perl make me think of an exit in awk.

Answer (score 2):

A Perl way:

```
perl -ne 'print && exit if $.==666' file
```

I tested by creating a file with the numbers from 1 to 999999. On this file, the Perl solution above and `awk` with `exit` are the fastest of those mentioned so far:

```
$ perl -le 'print for 1..999999' > file

$ time perl -ne 'print && exit if $.==666' file
666

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s

$ time awk 'NR==666 { print ; exit ; } ' file
666

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s

$ time tail -n +666 file | head -n1
666

real    0m0.021s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.000s

$ time sed -n '666p' file
666

real    0m0.125s
user    0m0.112s
sys     0m0.012s

$ time awk 'NR==666' file
666

real    0m0.161s
user    0m0.156s
sys     0m0.000s
```

That said, your original solution of `head -n666 file | tail -n1` is also blindingly fast, very robust and completely portable. Why do you think it's not?

Comment: can you time `awk 'NR==666 { print ; exit ; } ' `? I guess it would be as fast as perl.

Comment: @Archemar of course! You're quite right, that one is as fast as Perl. Add it to your answer.

Comment: @terdon: Yes `head -n666` is fast on your huge file because `head` stops reading after 666 lines and because 666 is much smaller than 999999. Still, that solution will have `head` output a lot of garbage for `tail` to read and dismiss.

Comment: @phs good point about 666 being smaller. My Perl approach is significantly slower when told to print line 999999. However, the `head/tail` or `tail/head` is still fast as anything, portable and efficient. I understand the aesthetic considerations and it would be nicer not to print needless lines but this all happens in the background and it is still blindingly fast. I'd stick with it.

Comment: Run `{ head -n 665 >/dev/null; head -n 1; } <infile` if you want to avoid reading and dismissing lots of garbage.

Comment: @don_crissti: That's great!! So many neat tricks popping up...