# How to get the number of bytes in just one line of a file?

Tags: text-processing, newlines, wc

I am wondering how I can get the number of bytes in just one line of a file.

I know I can use `wc -l` to get the number of lines in a file, and `wc -c` to get the total number of bytes in a file. What I want, however, is to get the number of bytes in just one line of a file.

How would I be able to do this?

Comment: How are you identifying the line you want to count the bytes in?

Comment: Do you really mean bytes or did you intend to ask for characters? `echo -n '€' | wc -c -m` will return 3 bytes, 1 character.

Comment: Yea, actual bytes.

Comment: The answers given assume you know the line number of the target line ahead of time. Is this correct, or are might you need to select a target line based on some other criteria?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
sed -n 10p myfile | wc -c
```

will count the bytes in the tenth line of `myfile` (including the linefeed/newline character).

A slightly less readable variant,

```
sed -n "10{p;q;}" myfile | wc -c
```

(or `sed '10!d;q'` or `sed '10q;d'`) will stop reading the file after the tenth line, which would be interesting on longer files (or streams). (Thanks to [Tim Kennedy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4721/tim-kennedy) and [Peter Cordes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/79808/peter-cordes) for the discussion leading to this.)

There are performance comparisons of different ways of extracting lines of text in [cat line X to line Y on a huge file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/47407/86440).

Comment: nice.  i was going to say `sed '10q;d' myfile | wc -c'`, but i like the readability of `sed -n 10p`.

Comment: @TimKennedy quitting straight after the requested line as in your variant would be better on large files! I think there's a question here with benchmarks.

Comment: I seriously need to study SED a lot more . . . .  Thanks guys!!!1

Comment: Good point about quitting right away.  sed doesn't try to figure out whether the given sed commands will ever print any more output.  `yes | sed -n '10{p;q} | wc -c` has a nice combo of readability and performance.  It exits right away after seeing line 10.  `yes | sed -n 10p | wc -c` runs forever.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
line=10
tail -n "+$line" myfile | head -n 1 | wc -c
```

set `line` to the line number you need to count.

Comment: I am sure there are still more possibilities to add useless forks.

Comment: @rexkogitans, you'll find that it's [generally faster than using a single `sed` or `awk` invocation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47407/cat-line-x-to-line-y-on-a-huge-file)

Comment: @rexkogitans, it will also work in the presence of NUL bytes in the input while many `sed` or `awk` implementations would choke on them.

Answer (score 5):

A little more straightforward using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==10{print length($0)}' myfile
```

Comment: Suggestion: exit after printing, instead of reading the rest of the file.  `yes | awk 'NR==10{print length($0); exit}'` exits right away, but yours loops forever (given infinite input).  Or with a file, wastes time reading the whole rest of the file from disk.

Comment: @PeterCordes better yet (IMO), skip the rest of the file with `nextfile` — that way the AWK script can be used to process multiple files!

Comment: @StephenKitt: Yes, that would be a better design.  Good thinking.

Comment: Or just `awk 'NR == 10 {print length; exit}'`. That's different from the sed|wc solution in that it counts the number of _characters_ as opposed to the number of _bytes_ and doesn't count the line delimiter.