# Viewing large (4M) files produced by the script command

Tags: centos, terminal, gnome-terminal

`vim`, `less`, `more`, `top` all hate files produced by the `script` command. `script` doesn't produce a text file. It produces a binary file full of terminal control info based on everything that happened in the terminal.

OK fine but I need to control replay better than `scriptreplay` seems to offer with a timing file. I want to move forward and back through it interactively. So I can stop it and read things.

A popular approach seems to be to convert the binary file to a text file. Theoretically possible but never seems to match. I've tried solutions using [col](https://superuser.com/questions/236930/how-to-clean-up-output-of-linux-script-command), [perl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output/18979#18979), [sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14699), and [awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47407/cat-line-x-to-line-y-on-a-huge-file). Perl came closest but still doesn't match.

I'm willing to lose color information but I want text to show up where it's supposed to show up.

Is there a better solution then just increasing the scrollback limit until `cat` works?

Comment: see https://superuser.com/q/236930

Comment: @Bodo Tried that already. If we're talking about trying to convert the binary file to plain text I got better results from a method [@dewtell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18979/141901) gave us. I was hoping to do better. It's really hard to simulate what the terminal would show without the terminal.

Comment: Did you try `col` as mentioned in the answers. Then, please, [edit] your question and write exactly what you tried and what's wrong with this solution. Examples might also help. This avoids that we propose solutions you already know. Make your requirements as clear as possible.

Comment: @bodo better now?

Comment: For that sort of thing, I use a script (`vile-pager`) which renders colors and same-line cursor movement in *vi like emacs*.  Presumably your favorite text-editor can do something similar.

Comment: @ThomasDickey where would I find this?

Comment: I believe *vile* is packaged in [EPEL](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/vile-9.8t-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html); the script may not be part of the package, but is in the [source](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/vile-snapshots/blob/master/macros/vile-pager).  Current version is 9.8v (I recall some bug-fix for typescript files around 9.8t -- see [source](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/vile-snapshots/commits/master/filters/manfilt.c)).