# redirect output to specific line number

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, files, tcsh

I want to `grep` certain lines by `keyword` and redirect the output to specific line number of an existing file.

### Command

```
grep "key" temp_file >> desired.txt
```

What I need is that I can append the `grepped` lines to particular line number say `x` of file `desired.txt`

Comment: You have a few good solutions below, but my question is simply, is this the best way to solve your problem? It makes sense, if this happens once. If you replace several lines in a longer script, it would make more sense to read the file (if it isn't too big) into an array, modify the array, and write it back at the end. That's because replacing a line in the middle is expensive - the entire file has to be overwritten from that point forward (unless you had fixed-width lines, then you could use `dd` and simply write over the chosen line in-place).

Comment: @mikeserv As I said, if this line happens once, just overwrite it, no problem. But if this grep line happens 200 times in a script, writing once from an array is obviously faster than overwriting 200 times.

Answer (score 3):

If you time the steps you take correctly, this can be pretty easy. Most important is to get a buffer of your source file that is not going to implode if overworked. The only real way to do that is with another file - which the shell makes very easy to do.

```
{   head -n "$((num_lines_before_insert))"
    grep key temp_file; sed \$d
}   <<SOURCE_FILE >desired.txt
$(  cat <source_file;echo .)
SOURCE_FILE
```

So, for most shells, *(to include `bash` and `zsh`, but not `dash` or `yash`)* when you get a `<<`here_document the shell creates a uniquely named temp file in `${TMPDIR:-/tmp}`, `exec`s it on the input file descriptor you specify - *(or, by default, just 0)* - and promptly deletes it. By the time it is served as input to your command, it is an *un_named* file - it has no remaining links to any filesystem and is just waiting for the kernel to clean it up before it disappears completely. It is a proper file - its data exists somewhere on disk *(or, at least, within VFS in the likely case of `tmpfs`)* and the kernel will ensure it continues to do so at least until you release the file descriptor.

In that way - for so long as your shell gets an actual backing file for the heredoc - they represent very secure and simple means of handling temporary file needs because they are fully written and all filesystem names are already removed from them before ever you read them. So their data cannot be tampered with while you work.

The above block first writes the temp file with `cat` and preserves any/all trailing blank-lines from the command-substitution with `echo` - which adds a single line to the tail of the file. From the `{` compound command `}` statement the output of its three three commands is written to `desired.txt` - two of which read in their turn from the heredocument the `head` and tail of the source file - and the `grep` command which inserts your `key` match.

I'm not certain if you needed this - but I thought it was relevant to show that you can simply and safely fully overwrite a source file with a sequence like this.

If your shell *doesn't* get an actual file for heredocs, you can emulate what it does like...

```
{   set "$$" "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}" "$@"
    exec <"$2/$(  set  -C
         >"$2/$1" cat  &&
         echo "$1")"  >&1 
    rm -- "$2/$1";shift 2
    head "-n$((before))"
    grep ... keyfile; cat
} <source_file 1<>source_file
```

...which will ensure all files are writable and safely assigned to file-descriptors before taking any irreversible action, but also does all filesystem cleanup *before* doing same.

Here is a test I ran to demonstrate this:

```
cd /tmp
set "$$" "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}" "$@"
seq 5000000 >test
printf line\ %s\\n 1 2 3 4 5 >test2
{   exec <"$2/$(  set  -C
         >"$2/$1" cat  &&
         echo "$1")"  >&1 
    rm -- "$2/$1";shift 2
    head -n2500000
    grep 3 test2;cat
} <test 1<>test
```

This first created two files - one called `/tmp/test` which was just 5 million numbered lines as written by `seq` and a second called `/tmp/test2` which was just 5 lines like...

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
```

I next ran the above block, then I did...

```
sed -n '1p;$p;2499999,2500002l' <test
wc -l test
```

...which, interestingly, took practically the same amount of time to perform as the insert operation, and printed:

```
1
2499999$
2500000$
line 3$
2500001$
5000000
5000001 test
```

So here's how this works:

1. The `1<>` redirection is important - it sets the O_RDWR flag on stdout and ensures that as each process writes into the file it writes over the file's previous contents. In other words, this means that at no point is the source/destination file ever truncated, but is rather rewritten head to tail.
2. The command substitution for `exec` gets the racy part done as soon as is possible *(or as soon as I know it can be)*. Within the command sub *noclobber* is `set` so if `"${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/$$"` already exists the expansion results in `exec <"${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/"` which, in an interactive shell will cease the whole process right away, or, in a script, will cause the script to exit with a meaningful error as the shell cannot `exec` a directory as stdin.
3. Within the command sub `cat` copies `source_file` to a temp file that doesn't already exist and `echo` writes the name to stdout.
4. As soon as all file handles are `exec`ed `rm` `unlink()`s the new temp file so its only fleeting claim to existence now is `<` the redirect it was just assigned.
5. `head` seeks through 2.5mil lines and writes over `source_file`'s first 2.5mil lines. The point is to seek through both files to equal offsets.

   - That in mind, this portion could be more i/o efficient if the newly created tmp file is on a tmpfs and the source file is on a disk if the i/o were reversed here and `head` read from the on-disk file and wrote to the file in RAM.
   - If you wanted to do that though you'd need to do `exec <>"$(... head ... <&1 >&0` to make the tmp file read/writable and maybe use `head`/`tail` with a specified number of lines for the tail end. In that case the number need not even be exact - you can [loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177570/52934) over input in similar fashion - advancing the offset only a little at a time. The shell's builtin `read` can be used to test for EOF - or `wc` can be used at loop open.
   - This is because `cat` will probably just hang on a `<>`stdin becuase it will never see EOF.
6. `grep` reads some data from some other file and writes it into `source_file` overwriting only as many bytes as it read from elsewhere.
7. `cat` corrects whatever discrepancy `grep` may just have caused by writing what remains of its stdin out to its stdout `1<>source_file`.

Answer (score 1):

Not really suitable for huge files but `ed` can `r`ead a command output and insert it after the addressed line, e.g.:

```
ed -s desired.txt <<IN
4r !grep "key" temp_file
w
q
IN
```

or, in one line:

```
printf '%s\n' '4r !grep "key" temp_file' w q | ed -s desired.txt
```

You can insert the output from different commands at different line numbers just keep in mind [you have to work backwards](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/181641) when `ed`iting via line number addresses:

```
ed -s desired.txt <<IN
48r !grep "another_key" another_temp_file
4r !grep "key" temp_file
w
q
IN
```

Answer (score 0):

If `desired.txt` is a very big file then you might want to optimize this. It can probably be done more elegant on the shell level but as I am not familiar with `tcsh` I suggest something that should work there.

```
sed -n '1,4p' desired.txt >file.tmp
grep "key" temp_file >>file.tmp
sed -n '5,$p' desired.txt >>file.tmp
mv file.tmp desired.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an `awk` solution (works with any shell, `mawk` and `gawk` tested):

```
awk 'NR==3{ while((getline x<"test_file")>0) { if(x~/key/){print x} } } {print}' desired.txt
```

**Result:** The extracted line will be printed at line 3.

**Explanation:** At line number 3 (`NR==3`), loop trough the second file (`while((getline x<"test_file")>0)`) and if the line in the second file contains "key" (`if(x~/key/)`) print that line (`{print x}`). The line ot the first file `desired.txt` should be printed anyway (`{print}`)

Comment: Why not split this into two commands. Let grep do its job and output to a temp file and then at `NR==3`, simply print the entire file at that location?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why everybody try to make a trouble from simple task?

```
sed -i "4a$(grep "key" temp_file)" desired.txt
```

(change `4` for any line number you need)

Or (for multy-line `grep` output)

```
grep "key" temp_file > grepped.tmp
sed -i '4r grepped.tmp' desired.txt
```

Comment: This breaks for backslashes and - depending on the `sed` -  other special characters.

Answer (score 0):

This will write the "grepped lines" to the lines AFTER the 7th:

```
Input="/path/to/the/file/you/want/grep/to/read/from"

Temporary="/path/to/temporary/file/with/grepped/lines"

Output="/path/to/desired.txt"


grep "key" "${Input}" > "${Temporary}"
cat "${Temporary}" | sed -i '7r /dev/stdin' "${Output}"

# delete temporary file:
rm "${Temporary}"

# all in one line:
grep "key" "${Input}" > "${Temporary}"; cat "${Temporary}" | sed -i '7r /dev/stdin' "${Output}"; rm "${Temporary}"

# OR without cat command:

grep "key" "${Input}" > "${Temporary}"
sed -i "7r ${Temporary}" "${Output}"

# delete temporary file:
rm "${Temporary}"

# again, all in one line:
grep "key" "${Input}" > "${Temporary}"; sed -i "7r ${Temporary}" "${Output}"; rm "${Temporary}"
```

Answer (score -1):

> $ sed '4 a\
>
> > `grep "key" temp_file`' desired.txt

Try this one. Option `a` is for after line no. 4. You can also give option `i` for before line no. 4

Hopefully this should work.

Comment: This is practically an exact duplicate of [Costas's](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182840/52934) answer.