# Fast method of splitting string from textfile?

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have a two text files: string.txt and lengths.txt

String.txt:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

lengths.txt

```
5
4
10
7
```

I want to get the file

```
>Entry_1
abcde
>Entry_2
fghi
>Entry_3
jklmnopqrs
>Entry_4
tuvwxyz
```

I'm working with about 28,000 entries and they vary between 200 and 56,000 characters.

At the moment, I'm using:

```
start=1
end=0
i=0
while read read_l
do
    let i=i+1
    let end=end+read_l
    echo -e ">Entry_$i" >>outfile.txt
    echo "$(cut -c$start-$end String.txt)" >>outfile.txt
    let start=start+read_l
    echo $i
done <lengths.txt
```

But it's very inefficient. Any better ideas?

Comment: How about `str="$(cat string.txt)"; i=0; while read j; do echo "${file:$i:$j}"; i=$((i+j)); done <length.txt` ..seems fast enough as done only by shell..

Comment: It's not a lot faster to be honest.  It's still taking quite a long time.  I'm quite new to linux/programming so if you think there's a faster method not only using shell, I'm open to ideas.

Comment: Try `{ while read l<&3; do head -c"$l"; echo; done 3<lengths.txt; } <String.txt`.

Comment: @jimmij, how about sticking that into an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do

```
{
  while read l<&3; do
    {
      head -c"$l"
      echo
    } 3<&-
  done 3<lengths.txt
} <String.txt
```

It requires some explanation:

The main idea is to use `{ head ; } <file` and is derived from the underestimated @mikeserv [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177570/80886). However in this case we need to use many `head`s, so `while` loop is introduced and a little bit of tweaking with file descriptors in order to pass to `head` input from both files (file `String.txt` as a main file to process and lines from `length.txt` as an argument to `-c` option). The idea is that benefit in speed should come from not needing to seek through the `String.txt` each time a command like `head` or `cut` is invoked. The `echo` is just to print newline after each iteration.

How much it is faster (if any) and adding `>Entry_i` between lines is left as an exercise.

Comment: Neat use of the I/O redirection.  Since the tag is Linux, you can reasonably assume the shell is Bash and use `read -u 3` to read from descriptor 3.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Linux has little to do with `bash`. The great majority of Linux-based systems doesn't have `bash` installed (think Android and other embedded systems). `bash` being the slowest shell of all, switching to bash will likely degrade performance more significantly than the little gain that switching from `read <&3` to `read -u3` might bring (which in any case will be insignificant compared to the cost of running an external command like `head`). Switching to ksh93 that has `head` builtin (and one that supports the non-standard `-c` option) would improve performances a lot more.

Comment: Note that the argument of `head -c` (for the `head` implementations where that non-standard option is available) is a number of bytes, not characters. That would make a difference in multi-byte locales.

Answer (score 8):

Generally, [you don't want to use shell loops to process text](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716). Here, I'd use `perl`:

```
$ perl -lpe 'read STDIN,$_,$_; print ">Entry_" . ++$n' lengths.txt < string.txt
>Entry_1
abcde
>Entry_2
fghi
>Entry_3
jklmnopqrs
>Entry_4
tuvwxyz
```

That's **one** command, that reads (with buffering so a lot more efficiently than the shell's `read` command that reads one byte (or a few bytes for regular files) at a time) both files only once (without storing them full in memory), so is going to be several orders of magnitude more efficient than solutions that run external commands in a shell loop.

(add the `-C` option if those numbers should be numbers of characters in the current locale as opposed to number of bytes. For ASCII characters like in your sample, that won't make any difference).

Comment: That's a convoluted reuse of `$_` as both output and input parameter to `read`, but it reduces the byte count in the script.

Comment: In a quick test (the OP's sample repeated 100000 times), I find this solution is about 1200 times as fast as [@jimmij's](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/222777) (0.3 seconds vs 6 minutes (with `bash`, 16 seconds with `PATH=/opt/ast/bin:$PATH ksh93`)).

Answer (score 6):

bash, version 4

```
mapfile -t lengths <lengths.txt
string=$(< String.txt)
i=0 
n=0
for len in "${lengths[@]}"; do
    echo ">Entry_$((++n))"
    echo "${string:i:len}"
    ((i+=len))
done
```

output

```
>Entry_1
abcde
>Entry_2
fghi
>Entry_3
jklmnopqrs
>Entry_4
tuvwxyz
```

Answer (score 4):

What about `awk`?

Create a file called `process.awk` with this code:

```
function idx(i1, v1, i2, v2)
{
     # numerical index comparison, ascending order
     return (i1 - i2)
}
FNR==NR { a[FNR]=$0; next }
{ i=1;PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "idx";
        for (j in a) {
                print ">Entry"j;
                ms=substr($0, i,a[j])
                print ms
                i=i+length(ms)
        }
}
```

Save it and execute `awk -f process.awk lengths.txt string.txt`

Comment: Based on the use of `PROCINFO`, this is not standard `awk`, but `gawk`. In that case I would prefer another `gawk` only feature, the `FIELDWIDTHS`: `awk -vFIELDWIDTHS="$(tr '\n' ' ' < lengths.txt)" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print">Entry"i ORS$i}' string.txt`