# Turn list into single line with delimiter

Tags: shell, text-processing

I have to take a list (loads) of IP addresses in this format:

```
 134.27.128.0
 111.245.48.0
 109.21.244.0
```

and turn them into this format with a pipe in-between (IPs made up)

```
134.27.128.0 | 111.245.48.0 | 109.21.244.0 | 103.22.200.0/22
```

I think it is a find and replace command like `sed` but I can't get it to work.

Comment: You just want to `tr`anslate newlines into `|` pipes? Like `<ipfile tr \\n \| >outfile`?

Comment: Is the space around `|` required?

Comment: yeah the space in between the pipes is required.  Please remember I am clueless so lets say my doc is in gedit  format and is called mydoc and I want to put it into a file called mydoc2.  would I then use the command as above as.   mydoc tr \\n \| >mydoc2 ???

Comment: @uselesslinuxman - no. You'd need the input redirect `<`. So `<mydoc tr \\n \| >mydoc2`. But that won't get you the spaces. For those, probably the quickest solution is `paste -d' | ' mydoc /dev/null /dev/null >mydoc2`

Comment: @mikeserv: your `paste` won't work in this case.

Comment: @cuonglm - oh man. What'd I get wrong?

Comment: @mikeserv: You will get separated lines instead of all in one line.

Comment: @mikeserv: I don't think it will work. `paste` writes lines corresponding from each file. Without `-s`, you will get back number of lines you have in file.

Comment: If you do not need the space around |, this `column ip | tr -s '\t' '|'` produces `134.27.128.0|111.245.48.0|109.21.244.0`.

Comment: Using your shell only `while read -r ip; do printf '%s | ' "$ip"; done < file`

Comment: @val0x00ff: I invite you to read http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/38906

Answer (score 22):

Using sed, based on [Famous Sed One-Liners Explained, Part I:](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one/): **39. Append a line to the next if it ends with a backslash "\"** (except here we ignore the part about the backslash, and replace the `\n` newlines with the required `|` separator):

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N; s/\n/ | /; ta' mydoc > mydoc2
```

should produce in `mydoc2`

```
134.27.128.0 |  111.245.48.0 |  109.21.244.0
```

Comment: @don_crissti sorry that was a type - corrected, thanks

Comment: This doesn't actually work in practice, unfortunately. At least, not for unlimited streams. When you do this you have to swallow the whole of your input a line a time and cannot write even a single byte of it to output until you have digested it all - all of it transformed into a single line. It's unwieldy and prone to segfault.

Comment: A million IP's is <16M, you'd need an awfully big list to blow limits here. Using search for eof detection is more problematic, as is this'll run O(N^2) on the input file size.  `sed 'H;1h;$!d;x;s/\n/ | /g'` is linear.

Comment: @jthill - POSIX only guarantees a `sed` pattern space of 8K; that's a whole lot less than 16M.

Answer (score 14):

I was curious to see how some of these (+ some alternatives) work speed-wise with a rather large file (`163MiB`, one `IP` per line, ~ 13 million lines):

```
wc -l < iplist
13144256
```

Results (with `sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` after each command; I repeated the tests - in reverse order - after a couple of hours but the differences were negligible; also note that I am using `gnu sed`):

*steeldriver*:
Very slow. Aborted after two minutes of waiting... so no result for this one.

*cuonglm*:

```
awk 'FNR!=1{print l}{l=$0};END{ORS="";print l}' ORS=' | ' iplist

real    0m3.672s

perl -pe 's/\n/ | / unless eof' iplist

real    0m12.444s
```

*mikeserv*:

```
paste -d\  /dev/null iplist /dev/null | paste -sd\| - 

real    0m0.983s
```

*jthill*:

```
sed 'H;1h;$!d;x;s/\n/ | /g' iplist

real    0m4.903s
```

*Avinash Raj*:

```
time python2.7 -c'
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    print " | ".join(line.strip() for line in f)' iplist

real    0m3.434s
```

and

*val0x00ff*:

```
while read -r ip; do printf '%s | ' "$ip"; done < iplist

real    3m4.321s
```

which means `184.321s`.  Unsurprisingly, this is 200 times slower than *mikeserv*'s solution.

---

Here are some other ways with
awk:

```
awk '$1=$1' RS= OFS=' | ' iplist

real    0m4.543s

awk '{printf "%s%s",sep,$0,sep=" | "} END {print ""}' iplist

real    0m5.511s
```

perl:

```
perl -ple '$\=eof()?"\n":" | "' iplist

real    0m9.646s
```

xargs:

```
xargs <iplist printf ' | %s' | cut -c4-

real    0m6.326s
```

a combination of head+paste+tr+cat:

```
{ head -n -1 | paste -d' |' - /dev/null /dev/null | tr \\n \ ; cat ; } <iplist

real    0m0.991s
```

---

If you have `GNU coreutils` and if your list of IPs isn't really huge (let's say up to 50000 IPs) you could also do this with `pr`:

```
pr -$(wc -l infile) -tJS' | ' -W1000000 infile >outfile
```

where

```
-$(wc -l infile)         # no. of columns (= with no. of lines in your file)
-t                       # omit page headers and trailers
-J                       # merge lines
-S' | '                  # separate columns by STRING
-W1000000                # set page width
```

e.g. for a 6-lines file:

```
134.28.128.0
111.245.28.0
109.245.24.0
128.27.88.0
122.245.48.0
103.44.204.0
```

the command:

```
pr -$(wc -l <infile) -tJS' | ' -W1000 infile
```

outputs:

```
134.28.128.0 | 111.245.28.0 | 109.245.24.0 | 128.27.88.0 | 122.245.48.0 | 103.44.204.0
```

Comment: don - could you also add in the suggestion in the question by @val0x00ff for the `while ... read` loop? I'm curious to see what 163k `read()` and `write()` calls translates to in a benchmark. Great answer, by the way.

Comment: @mikeserv - no problem, I'll do it (it will be [really slow](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/readline/) though).

Comment: That's a really cool link. I especially like that the author offers a link to a similar 6 year old benchmark there as well. Do you notice that `sed` seems to have improved its standing in that time *(and had probably only a very few changes to its regexp engine)* but `grep` seems to have dramatically fallen behind in its performance *(especially for the longer lines)*? I wonder if the `perl` additions to its engine have any bearing on those results... It's also neat that `dash` isn't *abysmal*. The `bash` here would likely be far slower w/ the common `IFS=` prepended.

Comment: hmm... that link is yet another strong indicator that I really need to buckle down and learn C so I can finally start using [`lex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) properly.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html):

```
awk 'FNR!=1{print l}{l=$0};END{ORS="";print l}' ORS=' | ' file > new_file
```

`ORS=' | '` set the [output record separator](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_03) to `' | '` instead of newline.

or edit in-place with `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/\n/ | / unless eof' file
```

Comment: thanks man. I just learned how `paste` works. much appreciated.

Comment: @mikeserv: You're welcome. as don_crissti shown in his benchmark, the `paste` solution is the fastest one.

Comment: The output does not end with a newline. You might have to replace `ORS=""` inside the `END` block with `ORS="\n"` so that it does.

Answer (score 6):

one-liner with tr and sed:

```
cat file | tr '\n' '|' | sed 's/||$/\n/'
134.27.128.0|111.245.48.0|109.21.244.0
```

Comment: Why delete 2 trailing pipes?  There will only be 2 at the end if the input ended with a blank line (two newlines).

Answer (score 5):

So I had the whole thing wrong - and this question has taught me a lot about `paste`. As cuonglm correctly notes, unless you `paste` an in file in `-s`erial, you'll always wind up w/ the last `\n`ewline from your infile list being appended to the output as it is written. I was mistaken in the belief that `paste -s` behavior was its default mode - and this is a misconception which, apparently `busybox` `paste` was happy to reinforce. The following command does work as advertised w/ `busybox`:

```
paste -d'|  ' - - infile </dev/null >outfile
```

It does not work according to spec, though. A correctly implemented `paste` would still append a trailing `\n`ewline for each sequence written. Still, that's no big deal after all:

```
paste -d\  - infile - </dev/null | paste -sd\| - >outfile
```

Comment: @don_crissti - dangit. stupid tablet. I guess the obvious thing to do is two pastes.

Comment: Well,  I had `pr` in mind but apparently it runs out of steam with huge input files so I couldn't actually test the speed but with reasonable length files it works OK. You solution is by far the fastest (no surprise - `paste` is really fast), see my post.

Answer (score 3):

Utilize `vim`:

```
vim -n -u NONE -c '1,$-1s/\n/ | /g|wq!' data
```

---

Explanation:

`-n` disable swap file

`-u NONE` is used to skip all initializations.

`-c {command}` execute commands after file has been read.

`1,$-1s/\n/ | /g` is `s/\n/ | /g` (replace newline with space pipe
   space) for the range `1,$-1s` (1st line to last line - 1)

`wq!` force write and quit

---

Note:

Depending on how big your file really is, this may be a bad idea.

Comment: I thank you all, because basically nearly every one of these commands works for what I need to achieve.  I know where to come now if (when) I am stuck again.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For completeness sake, here is another `awk`-based solution, this one is not using the `ORS` at all:

```
awk 'BEGIN { ORS="" } { print p$0; p=" | " } END { print "\n" }' file > new_file
```

For an explanation see my post at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/338121/117599.

Answer (score 2):

Through python.

```
$ python -c '
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    print " | ".join(line.strip() for line in f)' file
```

spaces before `print` was very important.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another one using `xxd`

```
xxd -c1 -ps data | sed '$!s/0a/207c20/' | xxd -r -ps
```