# custom delimiter for unix find results

Tags: find

I want to use `find` to find some files, and return all files as a single line (without newline characters), and a custom delimiter between the files.

So for example the result for three files would be

```
/my/file/1::/my/file/2::/my/file/3
```

instead of

```
/my/file/1
/my/file/2
/my/file/3
```

Is there any way of achieving this using standard unix tools in combination with `find`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Turn list into single line with delimiter](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/193863)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turn list into single line with delimiter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193863/turn-list-into-single-line-with-delimiter)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With the GNU implementation of `find` and `sed`, you can use :

```
find . -type f -printf '%p::' | sed '$s/::$/\n/'
```

- The `-printf` predicate of GNU `find` will print the file names in a single line delimited by `::` and then `sed` will substitute the last `::` on the last (here undelimited) line with a newline.

**Example :**

```
$ find . -type f -printf '%p\n'
./foo
./test file
whose name
contains newline characters and ::
./bar

$ find . -type f -printf '%p::' | sed '$s/::$/\n/'
./foo::./test file
whose name
contains newline characters and ::::./bar
```

The standard equivalent of `-printf '%p::'` would be `-exec printf '%s::' {} +`. There is no equivalent for that GNU `sed` expression as POSIX `sed` cannot handle non-text.

Comment: For the record: [availability of the expression `-printf`](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/find/#printf). Other `find`s will output something like: `find: -printf: unknown option` or `find: unrecognized: -printf`...

Comment: On macOS, you can install the GNU version of `find` using Homebrew: `brew install findutils` and use `gfind` instead of `find`.

Comment: If unfamiliar with `sed`, `head -c-2` is easier to understand. The number specifies the number of characters not to print from the end.

Answer (score 0):

You won't find -prinf in many find implementations. For those cases you can achieve the same by using the `-exec` command.

```
find "/some/dir" -exec echo -n {}"|" \;
```

`echo` prints every dir entry

The `-n` modifier avoids printing a new line character

The `"|"` character is appended after every entry

If your echo implementation does not support the `-n` flag, simple:

```
find "/some/dir" -exec printf "%s" {}"|" \;
```

The above will work in virtually any bash shell, including busybox which is present in minimalistic firmware oriented distros like OpenWRT or VMWare ESXi.

(*) Please, note that the printf call in the last example is external to find and not a find option as is posed in the first answer. printf as a binary is present in almost any distro you can think of, even the smallest ones.

Comment: You won't find that many `echo` implementations that support `-n` (though you'll find many that can't be used to display arbitrary file paths as they treat backslash specially) or that many `find` implementations that will replace `{}` with the current file path when it's not on its own in an argument.

Comment: The first argument of `printf` is the *format*. You shouldn't use variable things there (that will fail if the file names contain `%` or backslash characters). If you use a proper format, then you can use one `printf` invocation for several file paths as shown in the accepted answer.

Comment: That also had an easy fix. The accepted answer, which has been there 7 years so far, didn't take on account that many find implementations including some versions of Busybox's (some of the most used set of command line tools) lack the printf argument, thus I had to look for a workaround, which in the end turns out to be more wide compatible than the accepted answer. Not looking for a discussion on this, I'm busy, let people decide what suits their needs best.

Comment: The accepted answer has `-exec printf '%s::' {} +` (added after you posted your answer though) which is standard (`-exec cmd {} +` was first added on SysV circa 1983, specified by POSIX since 1992, but some `find` implementations like on some BSDs didn't support it until the mid 2000s, and it's possible stripped down find implementations still don't support it). `-exec printf "%s" {}"|" \;` is not standard nor portable. `-exec printf "%s|" {} \;` would be but runs one `printf` per file (less of a problem in some builds of recent busybox where that doesn't involve a fork+exec).

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
(){ print -r -- ${(j[::])argv}; } /my/**/*(N.)
```

To find all the regular non-hidden files under `/my/` and print their paths (sorted lexically, though see the `n`, `o` and `O` qualifiers for alternative sorting orders) `j`oined with `::`.