# Filter text from each file and turn it into a list of comma-separated values

Tags: text-processing

I'm trying to extract some information from multiple files and create a csv-type file.
Until now I got the extracting and writing to file part working but don't know how I could add a comma between each output or strip the newline at the end.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in folder/*.txt do
  grep 'sometext:' $file | sed '/^.*:\s*//' >> list.txt
  #doing simliar stuff with other lines in the current file
done
```

I tried to use `echo -n` to strip the newline but this did not returned anything useful.

What the code should do:
For each file in the folder find lines beginning with some patterns (ex. `sometext:`, `someothertext:` etc) and append the rest of the line and a `,` to a single line, corresponding to that file in `list.txt`.

Example of content of the file in the folder:

```
randomtext: ...
sometext: Hello
randomtext: ...
someothertext: World
somedifferenttext: !
randomtext:
```

Would result in on single line in the output file `Hello,World,!,`

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Why would grepping for `sometext` also match the `World` and `!` lines?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn list into single line with delimiter](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193863/turn-list-into-single-line-with-delimiter) so in your case `sed '/some.*:/{s/.*: //;H};$!d;x;s/\n//;s/\n/,/g' "$FILE"`

Comment: this would be done by simliar lines, see coment in script part.

Comment: @don_crissti I don't think that's a dupe. The OP needs to filter the text, not just replace `\n` with `,`.

Comment: @don_crissti your answer only works partially. It does not strip space between the de match and the rst of the line. If you could add that and submit it as answer I will accept it. thanks

Comment: @don_crissti yes, but that assumes a level of expertise the OP (or the next person to stumble upon this question) might not have.

Comment: after some trial and error I got the combination of @don_crissti's answers to work. But it seems to only append ',' if more than one match was found in the file.

Comment: If the input is YAML or some other structured document format, then rather than destroying the structure by applying `grep` to the document, it would be better to use an appropriate parser to extract the data you're interested in and transform it to CSV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, first of all do not use a `for` loop! That is very inefficient. Just give `grep` all the file names at once:

```
grep 'sometext:' folder/*.txt
```

In this case, however, I would use `awk` instead of `grep`. I made 10 copies of your input file to test:

```
$ awk '{
        if($1~/sometext|someothertext|somedifferenttext/){
            printf "%s,",$2
        }
        if(FNR==1 && NR>1){
            print ""
        }
    }
    END{ print "" }' folder/*txt 
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
```

#### Explanation

`awk` is a scripting language that reads its input line by line and splits each line on whitespace (by default, you can change that with `-F`) into fields. The first field will be `$1`, the second `$2` etc.

- `if($1~/sometext|someothertext|somedifferenttext/){` : if the first field matches `sometext` or `someothertext` or `somedifferenttext`. Note that this will also match `foosometext`. If you want to limit to exact matches, change this to:

  ```
  if($1=="sometext:" || $1=="someothertext:" || $1=="somedifferenttext:"){
  ```
- `printf "%s,",$2` : if the condition above is met, print the 2nd field followed by a comma.
- `if(FNR==1 && NR>1){ print "" }` : `NR` is the current input line number and `FNR` is the current file's line number. So, print a newline (awk's `print` call adds a newline by default, so printing nothing is like printing a newline) each time the file's line number is 1 but not if the total number of lines processed is also one. In other words, print a newline each time we start reading a new file.
- `END{ print "" }'` : also print a newline after processing all files.

Note that this assumes you only have 2 fields per line. If you need to print the entire line instead, you can use (using the version that only prints exact matches to illustrate):

```
awk '{
    if($1=="sometext:" || 
       $1=="someothertext:" || 
       $1=="somedifferenttext:"){
        $1=""; 
        printf "%s,",$0
    }
    if(FNR==1 && NR>1){print ""}
    }END{print ""}' folder/*txt | sed 's/^ //'
```

The difference is that we use `$0` (the full line) instead of `$2` and set `$1` to the empty string before printing. This results in an extra space printed at the beginning (because the empty `$1` is still considered a field), so we pass that through `sed` to remove it.

---

Alternatively, you could also do the whole thing in Perl:

```
 $ perl -lane '
    if($F[0]=~/(sometext|someothertext|somedifferenttext):/){
        push @k,@F[1..$#F]
    } 
    if(eof){
        print join ",", @k; @k=();
    }' folder/file*
Hello,World,!
Hello,World,!
Hello,World,!
Hello,World,!
Hello,World,!
Hello,World,!
Hello,World,!
Hello,World,!
Hello,World,!
Hello,World,!
Hello,World,!
```

Or, to also have the trailing `,`:

```
 $ perl -lane '
    if($F[0]=~/^(sometext|someothertext|somedifferenttext):$/){
        push @k,@F[1..$#F]
    } 
    if(eof){
        print join ",", @k , ""; @k=();
    }' folder/file*
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
```

#### Explanation

The basic idea here is the same. Perl's `-a` switch makes it behave like `awk`, splitting each input line into the array `@F`. Then, if the 1st element of the array is one of the desired strings, the rest of the fields (`@F[1..$#F]`) are is added to the array `@k`. If we reach the end of a file (`if(eof)`), we join the contents of the `@k` array with commas and print the resulting string.

---

Finally, here's one way to do it in the way you were attempting (assuming GNU `grep`):

```
$ for f in folder/*; do 
    grep -hoP '^(sometext|someothertext|somedifferenttext): \K.*' "$f" | 
        perl -pe 's/\n/,/; END{print "\n"}'; 
  done
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
Hello,World,!,
```

Comment: I need some time to read/test all of that

Comment: @Pit sure. I also added another approach that uses the (inefficient) `for` loop. That might be easier for you to understand.

Comment: I understand most of it, I just can't get any of the examples to write to a file.

Comment: @Pit just add a `> file.csv` at the end. Come into [/dev/chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) if you're having trouble.

Comment: I have some strange bugs which duplicates each line in output, but apart from that it seems to work, and I understand enough to expand the code to match all my needs. (I'm using the perl version)

Comment: @Pit the details will depend on your files. I would be happy to help but can only do that if we can chat and you can show me examples. Feel free to ping me (`@terdon`) in [/dev/chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat).

Answer (score 2):

With `gnu sed`:

```
sed -Es '/pattern1|pattern2|pattern3/{
s/.*:[[:blank:]]*//;H}
$!d;x;/^\n$/d;s/\n(.*)/\1,/;s/\n/,/g' folder/*.txt > list.txt
```

where `list.txt` content will be something like:

```
file1match1,file1match2,
file2match1,
file4match1,file4match2,file4match3,
```

so `file3` is missing from the output as there was no line matching *pattern**.
How it works: it processes each file `-s`eparately, removing (via `s/.*:[[:blank:]]*//`) the unneeded part on lines that match *pattern** and appending the result to the `H`old buffer. It deletes each line except the la`$`t one when it e`x`changes the buffers. If there's only a `\n`ewline in the pattern space it means no line in that file matched *pattern** so it deletes the pattern space. Else it removes the leading `\n`ewline, replaces the remaining ones with commas and adds the trailing comma.

With other `sed`s you'll have to loop:

```
for file in folder/*.txt do
sed '/pattern1\|pattern2\|pattern3/{
s/.*:[[:blank:]]*//
H
}
$!d
x
/^\n$/d
s/\n\(.*\)/\1,/
s/\n/,/g' "$file"
done > list.txt
```

Comment: I can't get it to work propperly, it seems to not add comma all the time. @terdon's solution is way easier for me to understand

Comment: @Pit - no problem. Keep in mind that people can only guess why it doesn't work for you. It's up to you to add details to your question and make it clearer.

Comment: I understand that, but due to the natur of the data, I can't release too much of it. So I can't make it any clearer.