# How to collapse consecutive numbers into ranges?

Tags: text-processing, awk, perl, numeric-data

Given a sorted input file (or command output) that contains unique numbers, one per line, I would like to collapse all runs of consecutive numbers into ranges such that

```
n
n+1
...
n+m
```

becomes

```
n,n+m
```

---

input sample:

```
2
3
9
10
11
12
24
28
29
33
```

expected output:

```
2,3
9,12
24
28,29
33
```

Answer (score 10):

With `dc` for the mental exercise:

```
dc -f "$1" -e '
[ q ]sB
z d 0 =B sc sa z sb
[ Sa lb 1 - d sb 0 <Z ]sZ
lZx
[ 1 sk lf 1 =O lk 1 =M ]sS
[ li p c 0 d sk sf ]sO
[ 2 sf lh d sj li 1 + !=O ]sQ
[ li n [,] n lj p c 0 sf ]sM
[ 0 sk lh sj ]sN
[ 1 sk lj lh 1 - =N lk 1 =M ]sR
[ 1 sf lh si ]sP
[ La sh lc 1 - sc lf 2 =R lf 1 =Q lf 0 =P lc 0 !=A ]sA
lAx
lSx
'
```

Comment:  this is the kind of answer that makes you wish you could upvote twice...

Comment: @don_crissti, if you're in to this sort of stuff, post the same question on [codegolf.se](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) and someone will implement it in Brainf**k.

Comment: I like this answer, but have two questions: ~~(1) How I provide `dc` the numbers via `STDIN`? I tried to remove `-f "$1"` and prepend and `echo "$numbers"` or append `<<< "$numbers"`, but it didn’t work.~~ I can use `-f -` and then `dc` reads the `STDIN`. (2) How could I replace the newlines with a custom separator? I have already replaced `[,]` with `[-]`, but I have no idea if I replace the newlines with `, ` (of course, I can do it using `sed`, for example).

Comment: @tukusejssirs Not sure I understand well what you want to know? Some implementation of dc don't get option at all, only files so for the 1 you can try echo '2 3 z p' | dc to print the number of values. first the values and after the code. for the 2, take a look at the man page for the commands n , p and c commands. Be aware that the c command is not always present. If the c command don't exist, you must have a trash stack.

Comment: @ctac_, I have solved the first problem by myself (I needed to use `-f -`). The second problem I wish to solve is to replace the newlines with a custom string, so that the output looks like `2-3, 9-12, 24, 28-29, 33` (I copied the example from the OP). Currenly, I can do it only with an additional command (like `sed`), but not directly with `dc`. Note that I have no idea if it is actually possible with `dc`. ;)

Comment: @tukusejssirs All can be done with dc. Hum, perhaps not the coffee! To get what you want, you must add 2 new macros. [ li p c 0 d sk sf ]sD and [ li n [-] n lj p c 0 sf ]sC. You must also modify 3 macros. [ 1 sk lf 1 =D lk 1 =C ]sS and [ li n [,] n [ ] n 0 d sk sf ]sO and [ li n [-] n lj n [,] n [ ] n 0 sf ]sM. It's not optimized but a patch for you.

Answer (score 7):

```
awk '
    function output() { print start (prev == start ? "" : ","prev) }
    NR == 1 {start = prev = $1; next}
    $1 > prev+1 {output(); start = $1}
    {prev = $1}
    END {output()}
'
```

Answer (score 5):

`awk`, with a different (more `C`-like) approach:

```
awk '{ do{ for(s=e=$1; (r=getline)>0 && $1<=e+1; e=$1); print s==e ? s : s","e }while(r>0) }' file
```

the same thing, even less awk-ward:

```
awk 'BEGIN{
    for(r=getline; r>0;){
        for(s=e=$1; (r=getline)>0 && $1<=e+1; e=$1);
        print s==e ? s : s","e
    }
    exit -r
}' file
```

Comment: Nice.  In the interests of compactness, `for(r=getline; r>0;)` could just be `for(r=getline;r;)`

Comment: And `(r=getline)>0` could just be `(r=getline)`

Comment: @steve `getline` returns -1 on error (eg `EIO`)

Comment: @steve. That's why the `exit -r` too --  that could be removed (awk will handle that itself on the next automatic `getline`) but I wanted the second version to be completely unmagical.

Comment: on my gnu awk, getline returns zero on EIO.  Example :  `echo foo | awk 'BEGIN{a=getline;print a;a=getline;print a}'` yields output of "1" followed by "0".  Man page : "The getline command returns 1 on success, 0 on end of file, and -1 on an error"

Comment: You're not simulating an EIO in your example, but an end-of-file. Try this instead '(trap '' SIGTTIN; gawk 'BEGIN{print getline}') &'.  In fact, only gawk handles errors on stdin correctly (as required by the standard), mawk/nawk/oawk/etc simply treat them as eof (they do warn or exit with fatal errors in some cases, quite inconsistently -- this whole thing probably deserves its own question)   **tl;dr** with `gawk`, `for(r=getline;r;) ...` may result in a infinite loop.

Answer (score 5):

Using Perl substitute with eval (Sorry for the obfuscation...):

```
perl -0pe 's/(\d+)\n(?=(\d+))/ $1+1==$2 ? "$1," : $& /ge; 
           s/,.*,/,/g' ex
```

- first substitution creates lines with "," separated consecutive int sequences;
- second substitution, removes middle numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Another `awk` approach (a variation of **glenn**'s answer):

```
awk '
    function output() { print start (start != end? ","end : "") }
    end==$0-1 || end==$0 { end=$0; next }
    end!=""{ output() }
    { start=end=$0 }
END{ output() }' infile
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another `awk` solution similar to the other:

```c
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

function output() {
    # This function is called when a completed range needs to be
    # outputted. It will use the global variables rstart and rend.

    if (rend != "")
        print rstart, rend
    else
        print rstart
}

# Output field separator is a comma.
BEGIN { OFS = "," }

# At the start, just set rstart and prev (the previous line's number) to
# the first number, then continue with the next line.
NR == 1 { rstart = prev = $0; next }

# Calculate the difference between this line and the previous. If it's
# 1, move the end of the current range here.
(diff = $0 - prev) == 1 { rend = $0 }

# If the difference is more than one, then we're onto a new range.
# Output the range that we were processing and reset rstart and rend.
diff > 1 {
    output()

    rstart = $0
    rend = ""
   }

# Remember this line's number as prev before moving on to the next line.
{ prev = $0 }

# At the end, output the last range.
END { output() }
```

The `rend` variable is not actually needed, but I wanted to keep as much range logic as possible away from the `output()` function.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative in awk:

```
<infile sort -nu | awk '
     { l=p=$1 }
     { while ( (r=getline) >= 0 ){
           if ( $1 == p+1 ) { p=$1;  continue };
           print ( l==p ? l : l","p );
           l=p=$1
           if(r==0){ break };
           }
       if (r == -1 ) { print "Unexpected error in reading file"; quit }
     }
    '
```

On one line (no error check):

```
<infile awk '{l=p=$1}{while((r=getline)>=0){if($1==p+1){p=$1;continue};print(l==p?l:l","p);l=p=$1;if(r==0){ break };}}'
```

With comments (and pre-processing the file to ensure a sorted, unique list):

```
<infile sort -nu | awk '

     { l=p=$1 }    ## Only on the first line. The loop will read all lines.

     ## read all lines while there is no error.
     { while ( (r=getline) >= 0 ){

           ## If present line ($1) follows previous line (p), continue.
           if ( $1 == p+1 ) { p=$1;  continue };

           ### Starting a new range ($1>p+1): print the previous range.
           print ( l==p ? l : l","p );

           ## Save values in the variables left (l) and previous (p).
           l=p=$1

           ## At the end of the file, break the loop.
           if(r==0){ break };

           }

       ## All lines have been processed or got an error.
          if (r == -1 ) { print "Unexpected error in reading file"; quit }
     }
    '
```

Answer (score 2):

A [nice discussion](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=87538) from 2001 on perlmonks.org, and adapted to read from STDIN or files named on the command line (as Perl is wont to do):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.6.0;  # for (??{ ... })
sub num2range {
  local $_ = join ',' => @_;
  s/(?<!\d)(\d+)(?:,((??{$++1}))(?!\d))+/$1-$+/g;
  tr/-,/,\n/;
  return $_;
}
my @list;
chomp(@list = <>);
my $range = num2range(@list);
print "$range\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a `perl` module called [Set::IntSpan](https://metacpan.org/release/Set-IntSpan/) which already does this (it was originally written in 1996 to collapse lists of article numbers for .newsrc files, which could be enormous).

There is also a similar module for `python` called [intspan](https://pypi.org/project/intspan/), but I haven't used it.

Anyway, with perl and Set::IntSpan (and `tr` to get the input data into comma-separated format, and `tr` again to munge the output), this is trivial.

```
$ tr $'\n' ',' < input.txt  | 
    perl -MSet::IntSpan -lne 'print Set::IntSpan->new($_)' |
    tr ',-' $'\n,'
2,3
9,12
24
28,29
33
```

`Set::IntSpan`  is packaged for debian and ubuntu as `libset-intspan-perl`, for fedora as `perl-Set-IntSpan`, and probably for other distros too.  Also available on CPAN, of course.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
awk '
$0 > LAST+1     {if (NR > 1)  print (PR != LAST)?"," LAST:""
                 printf "%s", $0
                 PR = $0
                }
                {LAST  = $0
                }
END             {print (PR != LAST)?"," LAST:""
                }
' file
2,3
9,12
24
28,29
33
```

Comment: I'd stick to lower case variable names, but that's just style. I came up with the same logic.

Comment: Actually, there is a bug here: if the first line is less than one, the first condition will be false, so the the first number will not be printed. You need a separate rule for `NR==1`

Comment: I might recheck. I'm not too happy with the clumsy logics anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

`Perl` approach!

```
#!/bin/perl
    print ranges(2,3,9,10,11,12,24,28,29,33), "\n";

sub ranges {
    my @vals = @_;
    my $first = $vals[0];
    my $last;
    my @list;
    for my $i (0 .. (scalar(@vals)-2)) {
        if (($vals[$i+1] - $vals[$i]) != 1) {
            $last = $vals[$i];
            push @list, ($first == $last) ? $first : "$first,$last";
            $first = $vals[$i+1];
        }
    }
    $last = $vals[-1];
    push @list, ($first == $last) ? $first : "$first,$last";
    return join ("\n", @list);
}
```

Comment: `24,24` and `33,33` is not quite what was requested...

Comment: As your awk approach is quite similar to glenn jackman's and mine, refer to those.

Answer (score 1):

Ugly software tools `bash` shell code, where *file* is the input file:

```
diff -y file <(seq $(head -1 file) $(tail -1 file))  |  cut -f1  | 
sed -En 'H;${x;s/([0-9]+)\n([0-9]+\n)*([0-9]+)/\1,\3/g;s/\n\n+/\n/g;s/^\n//p}'
```

Or with `wdiff`:

```
wdiff -12 file <(seq $(head -1 file) $(tail -1 file) ) | 
sed -En 'H;${x;s/([0-9]+)\n([0-9]+\n)*([0-9]+)/\1,\3/g;s/=+\n\n//g;s/^\n//p}'
```

---

How these work:  Make a gapless sequential list with `seq` using the first and last numbers in the input *file*, (because *file* is already sorted), and `diff` does most of the work.  The `sed` code is mainly just formatting, and replacing in-between numbers with a comma.

For a related problem, which is the inverse of this one, see: [Finding gaps in sequential numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867557/finding-gaps-sequential-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

On a "Unix & Linux" site, a simple, readable, pure (bash) shell script feels most appropriate to me:

```
#!/bin/bash

inputfile=./input.txt

unset prev begin
while read num ; do
    if [ "$prev" = "$((num-1))" ] ; then
        prev=$num
    else
        if [ "$begin" ] ; then
            [ "$begin" = "$prev" ] && echo "$prev" || echo "$begin,$prev"
        fi
        begin=$num
        prev=$num
    fi
done < $inputfile
```

Comment: Sorry, I never upvote answers that use shell loops to process text: it is [not only wrong](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/22142), [it's also damn slow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194015/22142) to do it with shell loops; take-home message: if you're using a shell loop to process text then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: How come to you 'dc' is the right tool to process text?

Comment: The text in this particular case consists of numbers and the task involves arithmetic which makes `dc` a suitable tool for the job.