# awk start printing based on a condition

Tags: bash, awk

I have test data in a file `text.txt`

```
a
b
test
test2
1,2
3,3
```

I want to output the file starting from the line number where test is + 2. I need this to be a oneliner usable in `gnuplot`, i have comeup with the following:

```
awk -v linestart=$(awk '$0~"test" {a=NR}END{print a+2}' $filename) 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="\t";lines}NR>=linestart{print $1, $2}' $filename
```

but i need somehow to supply the file contents to two `awk`'s which i do not know how to do. So i came up with solution with the `$filename` but this has the problem, how to get the `$filename` in.

I was thinking along the lines:

```
echo "test.txt" | read filename | awk -v linestart=$(awk '$0~"test" {a=NR}END{print a+2}' $filename) 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="\t";lines}NR>=linestart{print $1, $2}' $filename
```

but that does not work.

How else can i make the above work? The obvious problem is that i need to know the number of the line where i want to start printing before i run `awk`. i was also thinking something along this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="\t";lines=100000}{if ($0~"test"){lines=NR+2}; if(NR>=lines){print $1, $2}}'
```

But i did not even try it since, it is very ugly and not general, i have to make the variable `lines` always sufficiently big. So is there an elegant solution that would work with a normal text file pipe or in the other case with some way of pushing the file name inside?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `ed`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' '/^test/+2,$p' | ed -s file
1,2
3,3
```

In the `ed` editor, the command `/^test/+2,$p` would print (`p`) the lines from two lines beyond the line matching `^test`, to the end (`$`).

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '/^test/ { flag = 1; count = 1 }; (flag == 1 && count <= 0); { count-- }' file
1,2
3,3
```

Here, a line will be printed if `flag` is 1 and if `count` is less than or equal to zero.  The flag is set to 1 when the pattern `^test` is matched in the input data, and `count` is then also set to the number of lines to skip until the output should start (not counting the current line).  The `count` is decreased for all lines.

A slightly different approach with `awk`:

```
$ awk '/^test/ { getline; while (getline > 0) print }' file
1,2
3,3
```

Here, we match our pattern and then immediately read and discard the next line of input.  Then we use a while loop to read the rest of the file, printing each line read.

The exact same approach, but with `sed`:

```
$ sed -n -e '/^test/ { n' -e ':again' -e 'n; p; b again' -e '}' file
1,2
3,3
```

Match the pattern, then read and discard the next line (`n`), then get into a loop reading and printing each line (`n; p;`).  The loop is made up of the label `again` and the branching/jumping to this label (`b again`).

Comment: Would you mind explaining the first `awk` method? Specifically, where the printing done? I found that it seems to be following `(flag == 1 && count <= 0)` but i don't understand the syntax here.

Comment: @leosenko in `awk`, `print $0` is the default action – every record that passes the test `flag == 1 && count <= 0` gets printed

Answer (score 2):

If you know your data starts 2 lines after `test`, and there are no more lines with `test` on them, you can get away with something like this:

```
awk '/^test$/ { f=1 } f && f++ > 2' filename
```

Also, to send this data to Gnuplot, you might consider doing it through a pipe like this:

```
(
echo "set datafile separator ','"
echo "plot '-' using 1:2 with lines"
awk '/^test$/ { f=1 } f && f++ > 2' filename
echo "e"
) | gnuplot -persist
```

[image: Plot of the data]

Answer (score 0):

You can trivially do that with a `start, end` range with an end condition which is always false and a start condition which skips lines:

```
awk '/test/ && getline && getline, 0'
```

Comment: Don't do that as it can silently fail producing incorrect output or spin off into an infinite loop, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline. It's also not easily extensible to start, say, 50 lines after the target line (it'd require you typing `getline` 50 times!).

Comment: Can you give me an example input and awk implementation where _this_ will silently fail or spin off into an infinite loop? I'm especially interested if there's any awk implementation where `getline` can return _transient_ errors. Thanks.

Comment: Sure - any awk when the input file is or becomes unreadable. It won't actually go into an infinite loop in this case since you don;t have an explicit loop .

Comment: Not in my testing. They all seem to bail out on the first EIO (or other) error. I may be missing something -- my question was not rhetorical; I'm genuinely interested in an example.

Comment: And I'm genuinely giving you it but the input file would need to become unreadable after awk first opens it and before the first or 2nd getline executes - that's going to be tough to test.

Comment: I had used a special fuse filesystem for that (which times out, returns errors based on the file names). But I may have messed something up -- thence my question.

Comment: If you just always test for a positive return code from `getline` (which is what I'm recommending in that article I referenced) rather than a non-zero one then you don't have to think about the ways in which it might fail for any given application. Using getline for something like this makes it harder to enhance the code to do other things anyway though so I just wouldn't use it in this case as it has no benefits.

Comment: So I do [in general](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/470101/308316). I didn't do it here because I'm not convinced that the first getline could fail and the second succeed.

Comment: To me not testing for a positive return from getline when you think you don't have to is like not quoting your shell variables when you think you don't have to, etc. I'd much rather just not have to think about whether or not it's safe to not program defensively in a given context  and always quote my shell variables, test getline return, add IFS= and -r to read, etc., etc. People often ask me "how can getline fail here" and I usually show them a concrete example but I simply don't know all the ways getline can fail because I'll never use it in a way where I have to care.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '/test/{n=NR} n && NR>n' file
1,2
3,3

$ awk '/test/{n=NR+1} n && NR>n' file
3,3
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1745001