# Transform a single line, space delimited list of ips into a single column with each IP being a row

Tags: shell-script, sed

I am effectively looking to do the reverse of this question:

[Turn list into single line with delimiter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193863/turn-list-into-single-line-with-delimiter?newreg=5a887668fed1488c8fa391fd65cbf2c8)

where the best answer which worked for me was:

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N; s/\n/ | /; ta' mydoc > mydoc2
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide your input and expected output in this question. All information to answer a question should be contained in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `tr` command to change replace the `<space>|<space>` sequence with a newline character

```
tr -s ' | ' '\n' < mydoc > mydoc2
```

Comment: @Quasimodo, this answer (or at least its standard version `tr -s '| ' '[\n*]'`) would translate any sequence of one or more `SPC`, `|` or `LF` characters  to one `LF` (contrary to what the first paragraph says) so would address both cases.

Answer (score 0):

using awk :

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="|"} { gsub(" ","");print >> "mydoc2" }' mydoc
```