# select portion of file by line interval

Tags: sed, cut, uniq, head

I want to practice using `head`, `uniq` and `cut`, for this data [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lwubth4pdvsfv2v/data26.6.2015.txt?dl=0).
I know this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2072/16920) but it focuses too much on `cat` and external programs.

I would like a simpler answer.

I want to take interval from the data file, e.g. lines 800-1600. 
I am not sure if `cut` is intended for this task with the flags `-n` and `-m`. At least, I could not extract lines, just patterns in some byte locations.

### Running mikeserv's answer

**Code 1.sh**:

```
for i in 2 5
do    head -n"$i" >&"$((i&2|1))"
done <test.tex     3>/dev/null
```

and data

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

Running the code as `sh 1.sh` gives empty line as an output, although it should give `3 4 5 6 8`. What do I understand wrong in Mike's answer?

How would you select line intervals in data by `sed`, `tail`, `head` and `cut`?

Comment: `sed '800,1600 ! d' file`

Comment: `tail -n +800 file | head -n 800` (for `head` 1600 - 800)

Comment: Excellent answers! Please, put them to answers. I thought initially that this is trivial but now it becomes fun to think all combos how you get those intervals.

Comment: @Costas The second comment cannot work because the filesize is not 1600. You are matching from the end of the file 800 and and then from the start 800. You should chop off first 1600 to get it working.

Comment: @Masi try to to find difference between `tail -n 800` and `tail -n +800`

Comment: @don_crissti Where is cut and uniq in the other thread? Nowhere! I want answers based on these two. It should be possible.

Comment: @Costas You are right! `tail -n +800` gives everything after the match, while `tail -n 800` gives 800 lines from the end. Nice overloading of the flag!

Comment: @Costas I like your first comment a lot! How did you make it? I cannot find any detail about such an option in manual. It is very elegant!

Comment: @Masi - if you read the manual for `cut` and `uniq` you'll see why there's no answer there involving `cut` / `uniq`.

Comment: @don_crissti Naa. I have seen them combined with `xargs` and you can do nice things with these commands.

Comment: @Masi - I rest my case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in 799 800
do    head -n"$i" >&"$((i&2|1))"
done <infile     3>/dev/null
```

The above code will send the first 799 lines of an *`lseek()`able `<infile`* to `/dev/null`, and the next 800 lines of same to stdout.

If you want to prune those 800 lines for *sequential* uniques, just append `|uniq`. In that case, you might also do:

```
sed -ne'800,$!d;1600q;N;/^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P;D' <infile
```

...but a prudent gambler would put their money on `head;head|uniq` in a race.

If you want to process those lines for *totally `sort`ed* uniques, then you can still use the first `for` loop and append instead:

```
... 3>/dev/null  | grep -n ''      | 
sort -t: -uk2    | sort -t: -nk1,1 | 
cut  -d: -f2-
```

In the latter case it's probably worthwhile to `export LC_ALL=C` first.

Comment: @Masi - [`lseek()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) is the standard C lib function which enables an application to move *leftward* the r/w fd offset. In other words, it allows applications to easily rewind file descriptors. All regular files are required by POSIX to be `lseek()`able, but pipes and such almost definitely always won't be.

Comment: I added the output of your bash -command on a fixed input in OSX 10.8.5: empty line in the body of my question. Do you understand why it gives an empty line?

Answer (score 3):

Costas' elegant answer in comment

```
sed '800,1600 ! d' file
```

Comment: `!` doesn't mean _"unique"_... also, speaking of "elegantly", since you say you already know about the other thread I'm sure you also know the `sed` solutions you posted here will process the entire file.

Comment: You are right! Good addition!