# What is the fastest command to trim the header of a csv file?

Tags: awk, performance, cat, tail

I need to trim the header in a csv file. I have used `tail -n +2 ...` which works fine but it is really slow (I have lots of 100M files), and I don't understand why since no memory is needed from tail to achieve this (unlike `tail -n 10000` for instance).

I have tried `awk '{if (NR > 1) print $0}'`. It is a bit faster but still orders of magnitude slower than `cat`. But `cat` doesn't have that option.

Are there other commands? Thanks

Comment: Processing lots of 100Mb files is going to be slow no matter what. To remove the header, you will have to write the rest of the file out to a new file. That's what takes the most time.

Comment: `{ head -n 1 >/dev/null; cat; } <infile` though that won't work with all `head`s so you might as well try `{ sed -n 1q; cat; } <infile`...

Comment: @Kusalananda not really, as that's what `cat` does and it is 100x faster

Comment: @don_crissti the solution with `sed` worked for me, not sure why `head` doesn't. And it is really fast, thanks! if you want to write it as an answer, please do

Comment: Give a try also to this : `{ read -r line; cat; } <file`

Comment: Thomas, I'll leave it as a comment as this - and multiple variations - have been discussed a few times here (see e.g. [What's the best way to take a segment out of a text file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2072) and related questions...)